# What file systems on Linux store the creation time?

Tags: linux, filesystems, timestamps

Are there any (good known, reliable) file systems on Linux that store the creation time of files and directories in the i-node table?

If there are, is the "changed" time replaced by the creation time of an i-node in a stat call?

Comment: See also [How do I do a ls and then sort the results by date created?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20460)

Comment: There **does** seem to be a way to get the file creation time in Linux if the file is on a ext4 file system. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131347/182996

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) file system does store the creation time. `stat -c %W myfile` can show it to you.

Comment: Thanks. In my system `stat -c %W` returns 0 (creation time unknown), but that is another question...

Comment: But note that due to how files are handled by many programs, that creation time value _may not be useful_.

Comment: @mattdm: What do you mean?

Comment: @Legate: if a text editor works by copying the file to a temporary location, editing the temporary working copy, and then moving the temporary copy over the original on save, when is the creation time?

Comment: Does this need to be enabled somehow? I tried to get the crtime for a file on an ext4 filesystem and got zero. Having previously read [this blog post](https://moiseevigor.github.io/software/2015/01/30/get-file-creation-time-on-linux-with-ext4/), I also tried using `debugfs` and `stat` which revealed that there is no `crtime`. So I wonder if it needs to be enabled somehow? (FWIW I use *Arch Linux*)

Comment: @starfry there is currently no way for userspace to obtain the creation time of a file under Linux. `stat -c %W` presumably works on (some) BSDs, but it can’t output non-0 on Linux.

Comment: There **does** seem to be a way to get the file creation time in Linux. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131347/182996

Comment: This answer is somewhat misleading. Perhaps update it, e.g., based on the comments?

Answer (score 44):

Several file systems store the file creation time, although there is no standard name for this field:

- ufs2  → st_birthtime
- zfs   → crtime
- ext4  → crtime
- btrfs → otime
- jfs   → di_otime

Comment: To be explicit, as of 2015-03, XFS don't support (see `xfs_db` manpage or in [XFS File System Structure](http://xfs.org/docs/xfsdocs-xml-dev/XFS_Filesystem_Structure//tmp/en-US/html/index.html)

Comment: Just months after the prior comment from @FranklinPiat, XFS v5 did gain `crtime`: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/xfs/xfs-documentation.git/tree/design/XFS_Filesystem_Structure/ondisk_inode.asciidoc — however, it appears that some kernels capable of XFS v5 mounting did not support crtime: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306442/how-to-check-xfs-filesystem-version

Comment: xfs crtime still not visible using gnome nautilus or stat on some distros but later KDE Dolphin will typically show it: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=KDE-Finally-File-Creation-Times

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know ext4, JFS and BTRFS file systems all support an extra field in the files inode to store the creation time, though the naming might differ.

Source: [LWN File Creation Times](https://lwn.net/Articles/397442/)

Comment: // , Have you been able to verify this? AFAIK is sort of weak, for my taste, at least.

Comment: @NathanBasanese The AFAIK was reporting to JFS and BTRFS. For ext4, yes it supports it. Check `debugfs` command stat. Exemple: you need to thing the device where you ext4 filesystem is mounted (e.g. /dev/sda3) and you need to get a file inode number within that file system (use `ls -i`, let say 42000 is the number), then you simply type: `debugfs -R 'stat <42000>' /dev/sda3`. Run this as root, or with enough privilege. Look for the `crtime` field, that's the one. For JFS and BTRFS, you would need to find the equivalent debugfs command...

Comment: // , NIIICE. I tried $ ls -i | grep dump.rdb
656376 dump.rdb and $ sudo debugfs -R 'stat <656376>' /dev/sda2, but I think I don't have ext4 on there, yet. If I try it on an ext4, I'll say so.

Comment: @NathanBasanese You can do `df -T` to get the partition type or simply type `mount`. Make sure that the file inode belong to the correct partition. Inodes are (per their nature) specific to a partition.

Answer (score 4):

xfs v5 supports crtime

```
# dmesg | grep -iE 'xfs.*\s+mounting' | head -1
[   10.939721] XFS (dm-1): Mounting V5 Filesystem
```

shows using V5. Then get file inode number  ;

```
# stat -c '%i' test.txt
68227195
```

Then get crtime ;

```
# xfs_db -r -c "inode 68227195" -c "p v3.crtime.sec" <device eg. /dev/mapper/rl-root>
v3.crtime.sec = Mon Jun  6 15:13:02 2022
```

or on one line:

```
xfs_db -r -c "inode $(stat -c '%i' test.txt)" -c "p v3.crtime.sec" <device>
```

**EDIT**

...an easier way;

use `stat <filename>` for the same result returned as "`Birth`"

```
[root@wsa test]# pwd
/root/test

[root@wsa test]# ls
total 8.0K
67109562    0 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   22 Mar 22 00:07 .
     133 4.0K dr-xr-x---. 19 root root 4.0K Mar 21 23:54 ..
67552174 4.0K -rw-r--r--.  1 root root   10 Mar 22 00:07 test.txt

[root@wsa test]# df .
Filesystem          1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/al-root 104806400 25289868  79516532  25% /

[root@wsa test]# xfs_db -r -c "inode $(stat -c '%i' test.txt)" -c "p v3.crtime.sec" /dev/mapper/al-root
v3.crtime.sec = Tue Mar 21 23:55:55 2023

[root@wsa test]# stat test.txt
  File: test.txt
  Size: 10              Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 67552174    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0
Access: 2023-03-22 00:07:38.926108379 +0000
Modify: 2023-03-22 00:07:55.794041676 +0000
Change: 2023-03-22 00:07:55.794041676 +0000
 Birth: 2023-03-21 23:55:55.413859045 +0000
```

performed with;

```
Operating System: AlmaLinux 8.7 (RHEL clone)
Kernel Version: 4.18.0-425.13.1.el8_7.x86_64 (64-bit)
    
[root@wsa test]# stat --version
stat (GNU coreutils) 8.30
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    
[root@wsa test]# xfs_db -r /dev/mapper/al-root
xfs_db> version
versionnum [0xb4b5+0x18a] = V5,NLINK,DIRV2,ATTR,ALIGN,LOGV2,EXTFLG,MOREBITS,ATTR2,LAZYSBCOUNT,PROJID32BIT,CRC,FTYPE,FINOBT,SPARSE_INODES,REFLINK
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this - it was not an immediate search result 
it might be worth x-posting on https://stackoverflow.com/q/31233316/490487 ?

Comment: `stat 8.22` does not read crtime on RH7: stat gives `Birth : -` but xfs_db gives `v3.crtime.sec = Tue Apr 11 12:58:52 2023`