# How do I do a ls and then sort the results by date created?

Tags: files, ls, timestamps

In what order are the dated ordered by? Certainly not alphanumeric order.

`ls -lt` sorts by modification time. But I need creation time.

Comment: See also [What file systems on Linux store the creation time?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7562)

Comment: There **does** seem to be a way to get the file creation time in Linux if the file is on a ext4 file system. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131347/182996

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67895/286615) is current as of July, 2022, and correct.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Most unices do not have a concept of file creation time. You can't make `ls` print it because the information is not recorded. If you need creation time, use a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control): define creation time as the check-in time.

If your unix variant has a creation time, look at its documentation. For example, on [Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) (the only example I know of), use `ls -tU`. Windows also stores a creation time, but it's not always exposed to ports of unix utilities, for example Cygwin `ls` doesn't have an option to show it. The `stat` utility can show the creation time, called “birth time” in GNU utilities, so under Cygwin you can show files sorted by birth time with `stat -c '%W %n' * | sort -k1n`.

Note that **the ctime** (`ls -lc`) **is not the file creation time**, it's the [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) change time. The inode change time is updated whenever anything about the file changes (contents or metadata) except that the ctime isn't updated when the file is merely read (even if the atime is updated). In particular, the ctime is always more recent than the mtime (file content modification time) unless the mtime has been explicitly set to a date in the future.

Comment: In [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) it is `ls -c`.

`ls --help` shows what `-c` does when combined with `-l` and `-lt`.

Comment: @Aaron No, the ctime is not the creation time. It's a common confusion based purely on the fact that “ctime” and “creation” start with the same letter, but there is no relation between ctime and creation time. I've updated my answer to address this confusion.

Comment: LOL my bad. I was trying to confirm the Cygwin part for ya (IIRC your original post had a possible command). It does specifically say "ctime (time of last modification of file status information)" if I had paid attention.

Comment: Adding to @Gilles answer; I use an NFS 3.x file server (unsure on the underlying file system; it's either UFS or ZFS, though I'm guessing UFS).  Under Redhat 6.x: `-U` sorts by creation time.  Under Solaris 10.x: `/usr/bin/ls` does not support `-U`, `/usr/ucb/ls` supports `-U` and does sort by creation time.  These results obviously depend on the filesystem storing that info in the first place.

Comment: @brian-vandenberg, under RHEL7 `ls -U` is *do not sort; list entries in directory order* (I assume RHEL6 was identical). That's not file creation time.

Comment: @FranklinPiat, picking a nit here, but that *could* be creation order, if no files were ever unlinked from that directory. Incidentally, in FreeBSD, (and by extension OSX), `ls -f` will list directory contents unsorted.

Comment: @ghoti If no files were ever deleted (or moved/renamed/hardlinked/…) in the directory, then the directory order is creation order on some filesystems, but not all. That's not true on ext4, for example. I don't know if it's true on Solaris's UFS.

Comment: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+6.2-RELEASE – FreeBSD 6.2-RELEASE was announced 2007-01-15 ([notes](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/6.2R/relnotes-amd64.html)) with `ls(1)` option `-U` to use _time when file was created for sorting or printing_. [For `ls(1)` in 11.0-RELEASE](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE) the page notes that this option _is not defined in IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 (``POSIX.1'')_.

Answer (score 46):

Unfortunately, the `stat(2)` API does not provide a way to get the file creation time, as it is [not required](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) by the Unix standards.

However, some filesystems (as `ext4` or `XFS`), do save this information within the file metadatas. **There is just no standard way to get it, but there is a way**:

*Note: this answer mainly covers Linux systems.*

### UPDATE 2021: the new `ls` command option

According to [*Stéphane Chazelas*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119698/when-was-file-created#119699), the `ls` version from coreutils 8.32 (and glibc 2.28, and kernel 4.11) is now capable of using the new `statx(2)` system call (see end of this answer) to extract the creation time metadata.

So to list files **sorted** by creation/birth date/time, you can use:

```
ls -lt --time=birth
```

The `-t` option will sort by the type of time indicated with the `--time` option (I [suspect](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) `birth` can be changed by `creation` if preferred).

Add `-r` to reverse the sort order.

### `debugfs` for `extN` filesystems

```
debugfs -R 'stat partition/relative/path/to/file' /dev/sda1
```

You would get something like that mentioning `crtime` (*not* `ctime`!) if you use `ext4`.

```
 ctime: 0x513a50e5:d4e448f0 -- Fri Mar  8 21:58:13 2013
 atime: 0x513dd8f1:04df0b20 -- Mon Mar 11 14:15:29 2013
 mtime: 0x513a50e5:d4e448f0 -- Fri Mar  8 21:58:13 2013
crtime: 0x513a259a:35191a3c -- Fri Mar  8 18:53:30 2013
```

This command may take some time to return, probably because it also lists every extent related to the file.

### Use a VCS?

Now if you want to *order* files by creation date, I guess this is not easily (nor properly) possible. As *Gilles* says, it would probably be easier if you'd use a version control system. But you may try to have a look at the `ext4` API...

### The `stat` command (2021 updated)

I tried the `stat -c '%w' myfile` command on a `ext4` filesytem on a (recent enough) Ubuntu system without success (it just answers `-`).

**UPDATE 2021:** according to [*Thomas Nyman*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file#91200), the above command works on Linux if you have at least coreutils 8.31, glibc 2.28 & kernel 4.11. That does not sort files by itself though you could try:

```
stat -c '%w %n' * | sort -n
```

to achieve that. Use `%W` if you don't care about human readable date. Add `-r` option to `sort` to reverse order.

---

UPDATE 2020: since Linux [kernel 4.11](https://git.kernel.org/linus/a528d35e8bfcc521d7cb70aaf03e1bd296c8493f), a new `statx(2)` system call [has been introduced](https://lwn.net/Articles/707602/). Its API can give access to file creation time, if the info is available on the filesystem. To my knowledge, there is no standard/stable userspace utility allowing us to get this info yet, but it will probably appear in some time. This is not a standard POSIX interface though, but a Linux specific, says [the `man`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html):

> statx() was added to Linux in kernel 4.11; library support was added in glibc 2.28.
>
> statx() is Linux-specific.

Comment: If anyone want a one liner : `f='/path/to/file'; debugfs -R "stat $f" $(df $f|(read a; read a b; echo "$a"))|grep crtime`

Comment: Good update - I was just preparing to provide an updated answer myself, but you are ahead of me by almost a year  :)

Comment: re "*`creation`*"; Works on my cbk.

Comment: @Pacerier "cbk"?

Comment: @Totor, how do you abbreviate chromebk / chromeos?

Answer (score 9):

On Linux systems running kernel 4.11 or later, with glibc 2.28 or later, and [coreutils 8.31 or later](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils-announce/2019-03/msg00000.html), `stat` can show a file’s birth time on file systems which store it. Output similar to that of `ls -l` can be obtained with

```
stat -c "%A %4h %U %G %10s %.16w %n" -- *
```

and sorted output (assuming no filename with newline characters) with

```
stat -c "%.10W %A %4h %U %G %10s %.16w %n" -- * |
  sort -k1,1n |
  cut -d' ' -f2-
```

With [coreutils 8.32 or later](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils-announce/2020-03/msg00000.html), `ls` can display and sort using the birth time, using the  `--time=birth` option:

```
ls -l --time=birth
```

The `stat` invocations above use [these formatting options](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stat-invocation.html):

- `%.10W`: the birth time, in seconds since the Unix epoch (with a 10 digit fractional part).
- `%A`: the file type and permissions, in `ls -l` format
- `%4h`: the number of hard links to the file, aligned to four characters
- `%U`: the owning user’s name
- `%G`: the owning group’s name
- `%10s`: the file size, aligned to ten characters
- `%.16w`: the birth time, in human-readable format, truncated to sixteen characters (enough to show the year, month, day, hour, minute and second)
- `%n`: the file’s name

Comment: This is decently fast on a large directory!

Comment: See also `ls -l --time=birth` or `--time=creation` with GNU ls 8.32 or above (released 3 weeks after you posted that answer)

Comment: Thanks @Stéphane, I’ve added that to the answer!

Answer (score 6):

[Edit]
Use this command `ls -lct` to sort files as per `ctime` (*time of last modification of file status information*).

Comment: yup that is not the "correct" command, but it is what you are looking for in most cases

Comment: is there a way to do this with "find" so that it prints all files in subdirectories this way?

Comment: The `ctime` is change time, and not create time.

Comment: fair enough worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Perl script which uses Totor's answer to achieve what you want (if your filesystem is ext4).

Works on my home machine (Ubuntu) and my server (CentOS), but not tested beyond that, so ymmv.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl '2009';

use DateTime;


# Open the current directory for reading
opendir my $dh, "." or die "Unable to open directory: $!";

# Create a hash to save results into
my %results;
my %datestamp;

# Loop through the directory getting creation date stats for each file
while ( my $filename = readdir $dh ) {
    # Skip non-files
    next if $filename eq '.' or $filename eq '..';

    # Save the ls output for this file/directory
    $results{ $filename } = `ls -ld $filename`;

    my $stats = `debugfs -R 'stat $filename' /dev/sda6 2>/dev/null`;
    # crtime: 0x51cd731c:926999ec -- Fri Jun 28 12:27:24 2013
    $stats =~ m/crtime\: \w+\:\w+ -- (.+?)\n/s;
    my $datestring = $1;

    # Dissect date with a regexp, ick
    my %months = (
        'Jan' => '1',
        'Feb' => '2',
        'Mar' => '3',
        'Apr' => '4',
        'May' => '5',
        'Jun' => '6',
        'Jul' => '7',
        'Aug' => '8',
        'Sep' => '9',
        'Oct' => '10',
        'Nov' => '11',
        'Dec' => '12',
    );
    $datestring =~ m/\w+ (\w+)  ?(\d+) (\d\d)\:(\d\d)\:(\d\d) (\d\d\d\d)/;

    # Convert date into a more useful format
    my $dt = DateTime->new(
        year   => $6,
        month  => $months{$1},
        day    => $2,
        hour   => $3,
        minute => $4,
        second => $5,
    );

    # Save the datestamp for this result
    $datestamp{ $filename } = $dt->iso8601;
}

# Output in date order
my @filenames = sort { $datestamp{$a} gt $datestamp{$b} } keys %datestamp;

foreach my $filename ( @filenames ) {
    print $results{ $filename };
}
```

Comment: Also good to mention that some files may have metadata (such as exif) which record the creation date/time.  If all of your files happen to be digital photos for example, you most likely have this data. Here is an [example using perl's Image::ExifTool](https://github.com/jonathancross/j-renamer/blob/master/j-renamer.pl#L322).

Comment: Lots of warnings/errors in this..
Use of uninitialized value $datestring in pattern match (m//) at sort-by-create-time.pl line 43.
Use of uninitialized value $1 in hash element at sort-by-create-time.pl line 48.
Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/DateTime.pm line 197.
Use of uninitialized value within @DB::args in list assignment at /usr/share/perl/5.22/Carp.pm line 228.
The 'minute' parameter (undef) to DateTime::new was an 'undef'...

Answer (score 1):

To do it in shell.
ls do not provide creation time but change time.
Only debugfs can show creation time if partition is ext4

```
disk=$(df -Th . | grep ext4  |awk '{print $1}')
for file in "."/*
do
    inode=$(ls -i $file | awk '{print $1}')
    crtime=$(debugfs -R "stat <$inode>" $disk 2>/dev/null | grep crtime |  awk -F'-- ' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $2,$3,$5,$4}')

    printf "$crtime\t$file\n"
done | sort -k4 | sort -n -k 3 -k 1M -k2 -k4
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to find it in GUI, not in CLI: 
In Ubuntu 21.04, I can install KDE Dolphin File Manager, and see " Created" column in that file manager interface.

[image]

Comment: "As of July 2021, On Ubuntu", what does that mean? Does it work on Ubuntu 18.04 as well?

Comment: This still presumes that the file "birth"/"creation" time is even available on he underlying file system, which it may not be. Most modern Un\*x file systems and tools are _capable_ of tracking creation time, but many still use the long established tradition of only tracking "(a)ccess", "(m)odification", and "inode (c)hange" times.

Comment: @muru, I am using Ubuntu 21.04. I haven't tested with Ubuntu 18.04. The "As of July 2021" was mentioned there because this question was asked 9 years and 10 months ago; and things may change later on. Therefore, I thought it'd be useful to specify the date.

Comment: @C.M., I think I am well aware of that technical depth. Just to share from a simple level of end user experience with commonly used programs.

Comment: @qamnott that "as of" is then completely useless and misleading, since it doesn't provide the version info, and we can see when this answer was posted right beneath it.

Comment: @gamnott: _You_ may be well aware of technical insight, but not everyone who comes across this answer will be as knowledgeable. My comment was directed at your answer, not at _you_, as the "ctime" field from the stat() family of system calls is one of the more commonly misunderstood fields. Especially among those coming from a DOS/WIN programming background and learning a Un\*x system.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your explanation, @muru.

Comment: Dear @C.M., I have to sincerely apologise for my typing mistake and thereby rendering an unintended meaning of response. And I do accept and admire your detailed and helpful explanation. What I meant was that "I am not well aware of...". I am at a beginner level with Linux. Happy learning more.
(*I read these two new comments three times before adding.)

Comment: @C.M., please explain further. What does that date-time values refer to in that "Created" column as seen in KDE Dolphin file manager app that I am having on my Ubuntu 21.04 machine?

Comment: @muru, I updated my original answer to provide version info.

Comment: @qamnott: Not everyone who comes here seeking answers (or helping with answers) will have a "current" OS installed. Some may have older versions, and not all of them keep a record of file creation times. You will end up confusing some when you _assume_ everyone else has the same screen, with the same information, as you do. Take a look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file), for example.