# How to solve sudo: unable to execute /bin/ls: Argument list too long

Tags: shell-script, sudo, ls

When I run this command from php

`sudo -u db2inst1 ls -t /var/lib/edumate/bdrs/*/*/daily/*NODE* | sort -r`

I receive `sudo: unable to execute /bin/ls: Argument list too long`

ls lists all daily backup files we have for each customer. Customer has their directory under the `bdrs` directory. So I guess the number of files got bigger than allowed because it used to work correctly.

Is there any way how to get list of all daily backup files using one shell command?

Comment: `find` and `-print0`?

Comment: Do you mean `sudo -u db2inst1 find /var/lib/edumate/bdrs/*/*/daily/*NODE* -type f -name '*' -print0| sort -r`? - this doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather easier with zsh. Its `On` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) changes the sorting order to in reverse lexicographic name order.

```
sudo -u db2inst1 zsh -c 'print -l /var/lib/edumate/bdrs/*/*/daily/*NODE*(On)'
```

There's no point in passing `-t` to `ls`, by the way, since you don't care about its sorting order.

Comment: I do care about sorting :-) I need the files to be sorted desc by creation time.

Comment: @Radek Your sample command pipes into `sort -r`, which sorts by name (descending): the order of the `ls` output is irrelevant. You can't sort by file creation time because [most unix systems do not store file creation times](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created). You can easily sort by modification time in zsh: replace `(On)` by `(om)` (this is difficult to do without zsh). But for backup files, the name may be the right way to sort, if it encodes the date.

Comment: The filenames contain a timestamp. You're right ... I started with `-t` and then added `sort -r` and left -t in place doing nothing. Anyway, your code works and it is sorted as I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Convert it to `find` so that the expanded file names won't be in the actual command (right now the shell is "[globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)" which you don't want.

`sudo -u db2inst1 find /var/lib/edumate/bdrs/ -ipath '/var/lib/edumate/bdrs/*/*/daily/*NODE*' | sort -r`

Comment: It's taking too long. It looks like it will never finishes.

Comment: It was running for an hour and still hasn't finished ....

Comment: that's the sort.  it's not going to output anything until the entire find command is complete, and can pass it's full argument list to sort.  cut out the `| sort -r`, and you may see more visible progress.

Comment: How come it worked before much much faster?