# List files from time X to time Y

Tags: ls, timestamps, stat

How to list out all files created between from 'x' to 'y' time? I want to list out files created between "29-dec-2014 18:00"  to "30-dec-2014 18:00". Using ls or stat?

Comment: Hi, Please find the following url which might gives you a solution for your requirement, "http://superuser.com/questions/442490/command-to-find-files-for-specific-time-range"

Comment: @vembutech That concerns either access or modification times, not creation times.

Comment: @Gilles: an incorrect remark on your part. The OP asked for something that is impossible; a proper answer is to explain why that is impossible, not explain how to do something **different**. But at any rate, suit yourself.

Comment: Do you mean modified between those times? Unix filesystems normally only record 3 timestamps: last access (atime), last modification (mtime), and last inode change (ctime). Creation time is not kept (OS X is a notable exception, HFS+ has creation times).

Comment: If modification times are sufficient, see the `-mmin` option to `find`. You'll need to calculate the number of minutes difference from now to the ends of the time range.

Comment: Not enough information is given. For example, the ext4 filesystem records creation time. Is that what you are using?

Answer (score 2):

[Most systems don't track files' creation date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created).

If yours does and has GNU/BSD find, for example if it's [OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html), you can use its `-newerBt` predicate to compare the file's creation (“**b**irth”) time with a specific time.

```
find -newerBt "29-dec-2014 18:00" ! -newerBt "30-dec-2014 18:00"
```

This traverses subdirectories recursively. If you only want files in the current directory, make this

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -newerBt "29-dec-2014 18:00" ! -newerBt "30-dec-2014 18:00"
```

If your system doesn't track creation times, you might use the modification time instead. Replace `-newerBt` by `-newermt`.

Neither `ls` nor `stat` offer a way to filter files by time. All they can do is list files' timestamps, and filtering the output for a time range isn't easy. `find` is the right tool for this job.

[POSIX find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) can only compare the timestamp of a file with that of another file, so the portable way to filter files in a time interval is to create boundary files. You can only filter on the modification time, POSIX doesn't define a creation time.

```
touch -t 201412291800 /tmp/start
touch -t 201412301800 /tmp/stop
find . -newer /tmp/start ! -newer /tmp/stop
```

or if you don't want to recurse

```
find . ! -name . -prune -newer /tmp/start ! -newer /tmp/stop
```