# Change file creation timestamp on an exFAT volume from Linux

Tags: linux, timestamps, fuse, stat, exfat

## The question

As of today, Unix standards don't support a file "creation time" attribute. However, many filesystems, like ext4, exFAT and NTFS, internally do save a creation time for their files.

*Note: I'm talking about creation time (aka `crtime`, `btime` or birth time), not `ctime` (aka change time).*

For a while, even when using ext4 on Linux, this information was not easily accessible (need to use `debugfs`), but now, the new Linux `statx()` interface offers an easy way (API) to access file creation time, so that tools like `stat` and `ls` started to [integrate features](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created#67895) based on files creation time (read only though).

**MAIN QUESTION: How can I change the creation time of a file on an exFAT filesystem?** (using Linux)

## Thinking out loud

My guess is that it is not implemented yet on the full toolchain, so: **what is missing?**

- I know that [since kernel 5.7](https://fossbytes.com/linux-5-7-microsofts-exfat-driver-code/), the Linux kernel has a new internal implementation of exFAT contributed from Samsung. Does this new implementation (or any other) supports changing file timestamps (modify, creation...)?
- Is it implemented on the [linux VFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) side to change a file *creation* time?
- Is there any Linux API (kernel & userspace) to change file *creation* time?
- If not, would it be possible, given the current Linux kernel or FUSE implementations of exFAT, to (fairly easily) write a tool that would change a file creation time?

### A few resources

- This Windows-only tool allows such changes: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html
- This pretty much detailed blog article asks the same question and, as of now, says that it is not possible: https://miloserdov.org/?p=3069

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question but why should I feel the need to change the creation time of some file ?

Comment: @MC68020 Well, I have an Android app which apparently uses this creation time field to sort files (even though it says that it uses "modification time"). I copied some files from phone memory to SD card: that set creation and modification time of all files to current time. I put my SD card on my Linux computer to correct the mtime of files, but noticed that this specific app did not change its sorting, and used creation time instead. Also, I don't want to boot Windows to do something simple and useless like that ;)

Comment: I need something similar for my PSP memory card (exFAT). The PSP appears to sort based on creation time (crtime). I've spent >2 hours looking for a way to do it. I thought I finally found something with the (easy to compile) [fatsort(1)](https://fatsort.sourceforge.io/) program (which is maintained even). Unfortunately, it seems to alter sort order by way of changing inode numbers. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63867920/changing-the-crtime-in-bash. Lastly I've also found https://stackoverflow.com/a/63868920/558819.

Comment: A PSP community member on Discord told me they use [`PSPHBSort`](https://www.brewology.com/downloads/download.php?id=13265&mcid=1) tool for this. It's a Windows utility that apparently runs well with WINE. I'm looking for something to use from the CLI, but this could get one there in a pinch.