# Deleting files using xargs prints lots of No such file or directory (but seems to work...)

Tags: find, xargs, delete

I have a script that deletes files older than N minutes. The script basically runs:

```
find /some-folder/* -mmin +59 | xargs rm -rf
```

But for some reason it prints tons of:  `No such file or directory` but seems to do the work, e.g. see below example:

```
$ du -hs /opt/storage/
5.2G    /opt/storage/
$ find /opt/storage/* -mmin +59 | xargs rm -rf
find: /opt/storage/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss/jboss-parent: No such file or directory
find: /opt/storage/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/redis.clients: No such file or directory
find: /opt/storage/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.infinispan: No such file or directory
... 
$ du -hs /opt/storage/
4.0K    /opt/storage/
```

Any ideas to what is causing `find` combined with `xargs` to find files that does not exists? Maybe some race condition where files are somehow deleted before they are found/printed to log?

Possibly related:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/find-exec-with-rm-gives-unnecessary-error-747473/#post3646393

but mentions that the solution is to use `xargs` which is what I am doing.

**Update**: Based on below comments seems the issue is that deleting a file updates the modified time for the parent folder. Also files and folder will potentially be created during the deletion under the same parent/starting folder.

There is an example in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13869000/363603

on using `ctime` instead. But from:

https://www.webservertalk.com/linux-touch-command

*Changed time
The last time the file’s metadata, attribute or content was changed.*

so that would give the same issue.

If its possible to combine `find` with `--time=birth`:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/567590/11740

that would probably be the most robust solution but so far I have not found examples for this.

So there is no "standard" way in linux to do file retention (based on a date threshold) recursively from a starting folder while some parts of the subtree might be updated during the deletion/retention?

**Current solution:**
Based on findings so far I have split into finding all the files for deleting followed by executing the deletion:

```
# Store path to all files that should be deleted (potentially a lot!)
FILES_TO_DELETE=$(find /some-folder/* -mmin +59)

# Delete the file
rm -rf $FILES_TO_DELETE
```

Comment: The issue is that you are deleting directories with `rm -rf` that `find` hasn't visited yet. Are you sure you want to delete directories based on the last modified timestamp of the _directory_? That timestamp is updated when a directory entry is modified (a file or directory added or removed), but it is unaffected by things being added or deleted in subdirectories.

Comment: I want to delete all files and folder old than `N` minutes. The result of `find` is passed to `xargs`/`rm -rf`. I don't see how that can result in `No such file or directory`.

Comment: @Kusalananda is correct - you're deleting things before you get to them because the recursive flag (and `find`'s output is quasi-random). Just add `-type f` to limit it to files, and if you want them deleted then the flag is `-delete` without spawning more processes.

Comment: Let me put it this way: If nothing was deleted or added to the `/opt/storage/dir` directory for N minutes, but something was added to `/opt/storage/dir/subdir` just now, should `/opt/storage/dir` be deleted totally?  Because that's what you're doing.

Comment: Hm ok so since content might be added while I delete the only way to do this is to make sure I only delete files - e.g. using the `-type` f option? Then followed by a delete all empty dirs?

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting directories including its contents, and then delete these contents which don't exist anymore, hence the error messages.

---

It's probably not a good idea to delete directories based on modified time, so you might rather want to do a 2-step approach:

1. delete files
2. delete empty directories

-->

```
find /some-folder/* -type f -mmin +59 -delete \
&& find /some-folder/* -type d -empty -delete
```

---

If you really want to remove both files and directories, you could use `-prune` to not decend into directories that you already deleted:

```
find /some-folder/* -mmin +59 -exec rm -rf {} \; -type d -prune
```

---

Note, that I use `-delete` (only for files) or `-exec rm -rf {} \;` instead of `xargs ...`. If you want to use `xargs`, you should opt for null-delimited output using `-print0` and `xargs -0`. Some of these options might not be available in your `find` version.

Comment: Splitting like that - your first example - still gives the `No such file or directory` for most of the files

Comment: If for the first part I instead do: `find /some-folder/* -type f -mmin +59 -exec rm -rf {} \;` it works (meaning not Not found errors). So maybe the find `-delete` option is "unpredictable"?