# How to delete the oldest directory in a given directory?

Tags: bash, files, scripting, timestamps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shell script for moving oldest files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22674/shell-script-for-moving-oldest-files)

I have a backup directory that stores `x` other directories that require backuping.
I need something that will run before another directory is moved to the backup, that will check if the number of directories reached `x` and if it has, it will delete the oldest directory.

It should be done in a `bash` script.

Comment: A tangential comment: if you are looking for a rotating backup solution it's usually easier and less maintenance to find an existing robust solution than to roll your own.  Examples of some simple ones include [rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org/) and [rBackup](http://rbackup.lescigales.org/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Parsing the output of `ls` is [not reliable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Instead, use `find` to locate the directories and `sort` to order them by timestamp. For example:

```
IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%T@ %p\0' \ 
    2>/dev/null | sort -z -n)
file="${line#* }"
# do something with $file here
```

#### What is all this doing?

First, the `find` commands locates all directories in the current directory (`.`), but not in subdirectories of the current directory (`-maxdepth 1`), then prints out:

- A timestamp
- A space
- The relative path to the file
- A NULL character

The timestamp is important. The `%T@` format specifier for `-printf` breaks down into `T`, which indicates "Last modification time" of the file (mtime) and `@`, which indicates "Seconds since 1970", including fractional seconds.

The space is merely an arbitrary delimiter. The full path to the file is so that we can refer to it later, and the NULL character is a terminator because it is an illegal character in a file name and thus lets us know for sure that we reached the end of the path to the file.

I have included `2>/dev/null` so that files which the user does not have permission to access are excluded, but error messages about them being excluded are suppressed.

The result of the `find` command is a list of all directories in the current directory. The list is piped to `sort` which is instructed to:

- `-z` Treat NULL as the line terminator character instead of newline.
- `-n` Sort numerically

Since seconds-since-1970 always goes up we want the file whose timestamp was the smallest number. The first result from `sort` will be the line containing the smallest numbered timestamp. All that remains is to extract the file name.

The results of the `find`, `sort` pipeline is passed via [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to `read`, where it is read as if it were a file on stdin.

In the context of `read` we set the `IFS` variable to nothing, which means that whitespace won't be inappropriately interpreted as a delimiter. `read` is told `-r`, which disables escape expansion, and `-d $'\0'`, which makes the end-of-line delimiter NULL, matching the ouput from our `find`, `sort` pipeline.

The first chunk of data, that represents the oldest directory path preceded by its timestamp and a space, is read into the variable `line`. Next, [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) is used with the expression `#*`, which simply replaces all characters from the beginning of the string up to the first space, including the space, with nothing. This strips off the modification timestamp, leaving only the full path to the file.

At this point the file name is stored in `$file` and you can do anything you like with it, including `rm -rf "$file"`.

#### Isn't there a simpler way?

No. Simpler ways are buggy.

If you use `ls -t` and pipe to `tail` you'll break on files with newlines in the file names. If you `rm $(anything)` then files with whitespace in the name will cause breakage. If you `rm "$(anything)"` then files with trailing newlines in the name will cause breakage.

Perhaps in specific cases you know for sure that a simpler way is sufficient, but you should never write assumptions like that in to scripts if you can avoid doing so.

#### Edit

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dir="$1"
min_dirs=3

[[ $(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l) -ge $min_dirs ]] &&
IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line < <(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -printf '%T@ %p\0' 2>/dev/null | sort -z -n)
file="${line#* }"
ls -lLd "$file"
```

A more complete solution to the problem, since it checks the dir count first.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!
If I want to do this on a given direcoty, not the current one, do I have to cd <dir> before? 
because I replaced the "." with a path and it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @AAaa: If you replace the `.` with an (absolute) path it should work. If it were me I'd replace `.` with `"$dir"` and set `dir` to whatever I needed ahead of time. Otherwise, yes, you would need to `cd` first.

Comment: THanks. can you help me with a one liner for this? I need to execute it on a remote server via ssh so it would remove the directory I get. 
Also, Is IFS= required?

Comment: ssh host "cd $path;read -r -d $'\0' line < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%T@ %p\0' 2>/dev/null | sort -z -n);echo "${line#* }""
prints nothing..

Comment: @AAaa: You're running into quote-and-escape issues. You need to make sure that the remote shell is the one that expands the variables, not the local one.

Comment: This question is going to get closed as a duplicate, but you might want to adapt this answer for http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22674/shell-script-for-moving-oldest-files as well, since it's essentially the same procedure there, and this answer is really detailed

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like the folliwing:

```
#!/bin/sh    
keep=3

while [ `ls -1 | wc -l` -gt $keep ]; do
    oldest=`ls -c1 | head -1`
    echo "remove $oldest"
    rm -rf $oldest
done
```

it might be better to use `find . -type d -maxdepth 1` instead of `ls` though. it depends on the naming schema you use for the directories. if they are naturally sorted correctly by their name you can use `find`, `sort` and `head` or `tail` to get the oldest/newest directory. the `ls` approach uses the ctime attribute to sort.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
rm $(ls -t1 | tail -n 1)
```