# Delete the oldest folder from a path with an exclusion

Tags: shell, scripting

I referred the following thread [How to delete the oldest directory in a given directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28939/how-to-delete-the-oldest-directory-in-a-given-directory)
and the accepted solution is perfect. However, I have a requirement to exempt one folder that is the oldest. How I can accommodate this requirement within the solution provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adapt the [original solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28947/3645) to read files until it finds one that is not excluded:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' line
do
    file="${line#* }"
    if [ "$file" = './my-excluded-directory' ]
    then
        continue
    fi
    [do stuff with $file]
    break
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -z -n)
```

(`-d ''` is equivalent to the original, because you can't have NUL characters in strings.)

`read`ing a long list is slow though, and [@mosvy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472375/delete-the-oldest-folder-from-a-path-with-an-exclusion/472380?noredirect=1#comment862420_472380) is right that you can do the filtering with some rather nasty `find` syntax:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( -name 'my-excluded-directory' -prune -false \) -o -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -z -n)
file="${REPLY#* }"
# do something with $file here
```

Comment: maybe it's because I haven't had my coffee yet, but couldn't you just filter `./my-excluded-directory` with the `! -path` or `! -name` option of `find`?

Comment: find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( -name 'Development_Instance' -prune -false \) -o -printf '%T@ %p\0' , Where I want to find out the oldest directory other than "Development_Instance". The given code fetches the same directory as the oldest. I am going to try the longer code block provided by l0b0

Comment: I used the longer script that was given by l0b0 & added an exception for lost+found folder as well. Now, I can get the expected result using the script.

Answer (score 0):

One "sneaky" way of doing it would be to change the timestamp of the excluded directory at the start, and restoring its timestamp at the end:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ echo foo > example.txt
$ modified="$(date --reference=example.txt +%s)" # Get its original modification time
$ touch example.txt # Set the modification time to now
[delete the oldest file]
$ touch --date="@$modified" example.txt # Restore; the "@" denotes a timestamp
```

Usual caveats apply:

- This will fail to restore the original timestamp if killed before completing (or in case of power loss, etc.). If it's really critical to restore the timestamp you could use `touch --reference="$path" "${path}.timestamp"` to save the timestamp to an actual file and restore using `touch --reference="${path}.timestamp" "$path"`.
- The option names are based on GNU coretools. You may have to use less readable option names to do the same thing on other *nixes.

Answer (score 0):

No, that solution is not perfect, because it depends on a lot of highly non-portable features (`find -printf`, `sort -z`, `read -d`, etc).

My solution isn't perfect either, as it depends on the `-ot` operator of `test` (which tests if a file is older than another); however that seems to be much better supported (*bsd, busybox, solaris, linux).

```
# usage with_2nd_oldest 'command' files ...
with_2nd_oldest(){
        cmd="$1"; shift
        oz="$1"; shift; oy=$1
        for f; do
                if [ "$f" -ot "$oz" ]; then oy=$oz oz=$f
                elif [ "$f" -ot "$oy" -a "$f" != "$oz" ]; then oy=$f
                fi
        done
        $cmd "$oy"
}
$ with_2nd_oldest 'echo rm -fr --' dir/*/
```

This is also able to handle duplicate arguments:

```
$ for i in `seq 1 9`; do mkdir -p $i; sleep 1; done
$ with_2nd_oldest echo 7 7 1 1 3 3 2 2 8 9 5 1
2
```

For the other older question, where the very oldest file/directory was required, it's even more simple:

```
with_oldest(){
        cmd="$1"; shift
        oz="$1"; shift
        for f; do test "$f" -ot "$oz" && oz=$f; done
        $cmd "$oz"
}
```

Both can be trivially adapted to skip arbitrary paths, or to read the list of files from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
rm -rf -- ^that-folder-to-keep(D/Om[1])
```

With the solution provided at that other Q&A:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' line < <(
  find . -maxdepth 1 \
    ! -name that-folder-to-keep \
    -type d -printf '%T@ %p\0' 2>/dev/null | sort -z -n) &&
  rm -rf "${line#* }"
```

If you want to remove the second oldest:

`zsh`:

```
rm -rf -- *(D/Om[2])
```

GNU utilities:

```
{ IFS= read -r -d '' line &&
  IFS= read -r -d '' line &&; } < <(
  find . -maxdepth 1 \
    -type d -printf '%T@ %p\0' 2>/dev/null | sort -z -n) &&
  rm -rf "${line#* }"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r -d '' line
do
    file="${line#* }"
    if [ "$file" = './Development_Instance' ]
    then
        continue
fi

if [ "$file" = './lost+found' ]
then
continue
fi
    echo $file
    break
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -z -n)
```

That's how I managed. I know it is not the elegant way to do it. It just does the thing for me.