# How to write bash script that deletes the oldest file in a directory if there are greater than N files in the directory?

Tags: bash, scripting

Wondering how would one go about writing a script that:

Counts the number of files in a directory.

If that number is greater than a specified number N, delete the oldest file in the directory.

For bonus feelings of good will: Only included .zip files in the count/delete.

Comment: This feels a little like we may be doing school or real work for @Ryan. Perhaps you can demonstrate what you have come up with so far.

Comment: @uther Not for work, for a world backup on a personal Minecraft server. If you don't want to help, that's OK. So far I just have a script that copies files to a location, but it will fill up the drive unless I know how to do the script requested above.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to help, otherwise I wouldn't spend time here. What you are asking for is fairly trivial. It would go a long way to see you make an effort to write a script first and ask for critique/improvements instead of asking someone to write the script for you from scratch. I want you to learn something.

Comment: man `find`, man  `wc`, man `ls`

Comment: Why all the down-votes?  BTW, possibly [relevant reading](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004).

Comment: When you mouse over the downvote button it says: "This question does not show any research effort".  If that doesn't apply here, when does it apply?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I voted to close for the wrong duplicate. I should have picked [Shell script for moving oldest files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22674) or [Bash, remove oldest files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35792)

Comment: @uther it's only trivial if you have more experience...

Answer (score 1):

```
N=50
[[ $( ls | wc -l ) -gt $N ]] && ls -tr | tail -n1 | tr \\n \\0 | xargs -0 echo rm
```

Barely tested, but I think this comes close. If you are happy with the text output, you can remove the `echo` to set it live.

- `ls` list files
- `wc` count them
- `[[ ... -gt ... ]]` if
- `&&` then
- `ls -tr` list files in reverse age
- `tail -n1` show only last line (replace `1` as needed)
- `tr \\n \\0` make `\0` the delimiter between filenames (only one here)
- `xargs -0 echo rm --` append every argument (delimited by `\0`s) found to `echo rm --`
- `echo rm --` give you the opportunity to check if the result is really what you want
- `rm --` remove file (put `--` before filenames to handle filenames starting with `-`)

Comment: This will break on filenames containing newlines.

Comment: This will break on filenames containing any kind of whitespace or `\'"`.

Comment: Schoolbook assignments don't have newlines and quotes in filenames. ;o)

Comment: @jippie this is for my minecraft server backups :)

Comment: Same for minecraft server backups ;o)   (just guessing)

Answer (score 1):

For example, to only perform the actions if there are more than 50 files in the folder:

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob
for file in *; do
    [[ -f $file ]] && files+=( "$file" )
done
if (( ${#files[@]} > 50 )); then
    IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' 2>/dev/null | sort -z -n)
    rm "${line#* }"
fi
```