# Delete oldest files from a directory if number exceeds seven

Tags: shell-script, files

Daily downloads are stored in a directory.

A script has been created which counts how many files reside in this folder.

The part I am struggling with is deleting the oldest file in the directory if the number of files exceeds seven.

How should I proceed?

```
# If I tared it up would the target exist
tar_file=$FTP_DIR/`basename $newest`.tar
if [-s "$tar_file" ]
then
    echo Files Found
else
    echo No files
fi

# tar it up
tar -cf tar_file.tar $newest

# how many tar files do I now have
fc=$(ls | wc -l)
echo $fc

# If more than 7 delete the oldest ones
```

Comment: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3071/33055

Comment: You probably mean `echo $file_count` at the end?

Comment: Can you clarify which files to delete? You write "deleting the oldest file" in the text, but "the oldest ones" in the code comment, last line. If the question is clear, the question and the answers can help other users too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this Q&A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22674/shell-script-for-moving-oldest-files?rq=1)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
if [ $file_count -gt 7 ]
    rm `/bin/ls -rt | head -1`
fi
```

Comment: This deletes the **newest** file, and does not work with **space** in the names.

Comment: Re newest file:  fixed.  Re spaces: I never claimed that I was going to write a bulletproof solution.  I gave him a line that would do what he wanted.  If you're going to do something foolish like use spaces in your file names, then you deserve what you get.  All you probably need are some double-quotes in the right place though to handle them.

Comment: How is using space in filenames stupid? You may not have  control over the file names used by software you need. The OP does not even know the names before, as it is about downloads.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question.  But landed here and sharing in case someone else needs it.

```
#!/bin/bash
FTP_DIR=/var/lib/ftp # change to location of dir
FILESTOKEEP=7

ls -1t $FTP_DIR/*.tar | awk -v FILESTOKEEP=$FILESTOKEEP '{if (NR>FILESTOKEEP) print $0}' | xargs rm
```

Basically I list all file in a single column `-1` sort by modification time, newest first `-t`

Then using `awk` I set a var with the number of files specified by `$FILESTOKEEP`  and print record greater than that.

Passing the results to `xargs` to which will run `rm` on each line of output by `awk`

This will work if the script is not called within the folder that holds the file since using a wildcard in `ls` will force to print the expanded path.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score -1):

**Code**

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ cat rm_gt_7_days
d=/tmp/test
fc=$(ls $d| wc -l)

if [ "$fc" -gt "7" ]; then
        find $d/* -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
fi
```

**Test**

*Directory and files*

```
mkdir /tmp/test && \
for f in `seq 7`; do touch /tmp/test/test${f}; done && \
touch -t 201203101513 /tmp/test/test8
```

*Overview*

```
[vagrant@localhost /]$ ll /tmp/test
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 14 12:47 test1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 14 12:47 test2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 14 12:47 test3
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 14 12:47 test4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 14 12:47 test5
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 14 12:47 test6
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 14 12:47 test7
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Mar 10  2012 test8
```

*Execution of script and outcome*

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sh rm_gt_7_days
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ll /tmp/test
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 14 12:47 test1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 14 12:47 test2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 14 12:47 test3
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 14 12:47 test4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 14 12:47 test5
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 14 12:47 test6
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 14 12:47 test7
```

**Sources**

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/62492/how-can-i-change-the-date-modified-created-of-a-file
2. http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/unix-shell-scripting/ifelse-tutorial.php
3. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/delete-files-older-than-x-days-on-linux/
4. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-generating-print-range-sequence-of-numbers.html

Comment: This deletes files by how long ago the last modification was, and could delete all files. The example also finds files in other directories than `/tmp/test`, like `/tmp/testfoo/bar.txt`.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Issue regarding `/tmp/test*` solved by changing it to `/tmp/test/*`

Comment: @VolkerSiegel According to [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842195/how-to-get-file-creation-date-time-in-bash-debian) the creation date is stored nowhere

Comment: That's true - what I mean is that the question is not about how long ago the last file modification or creation was.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Regarding `sudo`. This can be omitted indeed. The answer has been updated.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Ok. I will update the answer once the question has been clarified.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you are trying to delete the tar files or the $newest files.  But for general files in a single directory:

```
ls -t1 $dir | tail -n +8 | while read filename; do rm "$filename"; done
```

This should take care of if there are a) less than 7 files and b) whitespace in the filename (except a newline).

The `tail` command can take a positive to get the last lines starting from the beginning.

Comment: Good solution, except that `ls -t1 $dir` won't give absolute paths, so `rm` won't delete anything unless `$dir == .`. You could surround this with `pushd $dir` / `popd`.