# Delete oldest file with a shell script on FTP server

Tags: shell-script, rm, vps

I would like to create a cron job for deleting the oldest file in a directory which is on FTP server. I have created my first shell script

```
#!/bin/sh

# connect to backup FTP server...
lftp -u (username),password backup.contabo.net << EOF
cd /backups
ls

EOF
```

This is what I get http://image.prntscr.com/image/72a86bf453c849a8af4a3340e4936172.jpeg

I did some searching and the following line worked when I tested it in the terminal inside a test folder on VPS (with some newly created .txt files):

```
rm "$(ls -t | tail -1)"
```

...but when I place it inside the shell script and when I run it with `bash testing.sh` I get

**rm: Access failed: 550 index.php: No such file or directory**

Why is the script trying to delete index.php? I don't even see it inside file listing. 
It should delete `01December_01_2016_html.tar`

**EDIT**
Ok I finally succeeded to delete file but with manually writing the filename.

```
rm /backups/01December_01_2016_html.tar
```

So I was thinking to first create a variable with the filename so I can pass it to `rm /backups/$FILENAME.tar` or similar, I haven't done this because the following code is giving me the error - `Unknown command 'FILENAME="testing.sh"`
This is basically the same thing, it means I get the latest file on local directory and not in the FTP directory (even though single `ls` worked OK for retrieving all files)

```
FILENAME="$(ls -t | tail -1)"
echo $FILENAME
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell script for moving oldest files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22674/shell-script-for-moving-oldest-files)

Comment: Set 1st line to be #!/bin/sh

Comment: I think you want to delete a file inside of a FTP server, right? Perhaps with your `rm` of your `ls` output you are getting the file from your local directory (which may have the index.php file), not the remote directory, do you have it?

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio That is true, how can I delete it on FTP server?

Comment: You'll need to write a shell script that first queries the FTP server for the directory listing, then sorts out what file is the oldest, then issues the `rm` to the FTP server. That's two separate transactions to the FTP server, but you can't run a shell script "on the FTP server".

Comment: @muru Not a dupe. OP wants to delete on the FTP server and via FTP.

Comment: @xhienne since OP can access the server without FTP to run shell commands, I don't see why it has to be FTP

Comment: @muru Didn't see where this is written. But the code posted in the question, and the text that folllows, show clearly that the OP wants to clean-up things remotely with `lftp`.

Comment: @xhienne "I tested it in the terminal inside a test folder on VPS..." And  OP might "want" to do X, but that doesn't mean Y isn't the better solution. Not interested in arguing further.