# xargs: 'ls' terminated by signal 13

Tags: find, ls, xargs

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ltr | head -n 10 | awk '{print
$NF}' | xargs rm
```

This command is giving me this:

```
xargs: 'ls' terminated by signal 13
```

However, it's executing fine. It's supposed to delete the 10 oldest files on the specific folder. Is there something to worry about? Is there a fix?

Server is running BuildRoot.

Comment: A better way to sort files, especially lots of files - so many that  xargs would issue multiple invocations of `ls` and you wouldn't get a total sort - can be found at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22674/shell-script-for-moving-oldest-files

Comment: Signal numbers other then 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 14, and 15 are not portable. You need to explain what signal 13 is on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is with the head command and the pipe.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800726/ls-terminated-by-signal-13-when-using-xargs for more information.