# Birth is empty on ext4

Tags: filesystems, ext4, stat

I was just reading up on the `Birth` section of `stat` and it appears ext4 should support it, but even a file I just created leaves it empty.

```
 ~  % touch test                                                       slave-iv
 ~  % stat test.pl                                                     slave-iv
  File: ‘test.pl’
  Size: 173             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 903h/2307d      Inode: 41943086    Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/xenoterracide)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2012-09-22 18:22:16.924634497 -0500
Modify: 2012-09-22 18:22:16.924634497 -0500
Change: 2012-09-22 18:22:16.947967935 -0500
 Birth: -

 ~  % sudo tune2fs -l /dev/md3 | psp4                                  slave-iv
tune2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Filesystem volume name:   home
Last mounted on:          /home
Filesystem UUID:          ab2e39fb-acdd-416a-9e10-b501498056de
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    journal_data
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              59736064
Block count:              238920960
Reserved block count:     11946048
Free blocks:              34486248
Free inodes:              59610013
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      967
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
RAID stride:              128
RAID stripe width:        256
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Mon May 31 20:36:30 2010
Last mount time:          Sat Oct  6 11:01:01 2012
Last write time:          Sat Oct  6 11:01:01 2012
Mount count:              14
Maximum mount count:      34
Last checked:             Tue Jul 10 08:26:37 2012
Check interval:           15552000 (6 months)
Next check after:         Sun Jan  6 07:26:37 2013
Lifetime writes:          7255 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       55313243
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      442c66e8-8b67-4a8c-92a6-2e2d0c220044
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

Why doesn't my `ext4` partition populate this field?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The field gets populated (see below) only `coreutils stat` does not display it. Apparently they're waiting<sup>1</sup> for the [`xstat()` interface](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-findutils/2011-11/msg00015.html).

[coreutils patches - aug. 2012 - TODO](http://www.pixelbeat.org/patches/coreutils/inbox_aug_2012.html)

> stat(1) and ls(1) support for birth time. Dependent on xstat() being
>   provided by the kernel

You can get the creation time via `debugfs`:

```sh
debugfs -R 'stat <inode_number>' DEVICE
```

e.g. for my `/etc/profile` which is on `/dev/sda2` (see [How to find out what device a file is on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65736)):

```
stat -c %i /etc/profile
398264
```

```sh
debugfs -R 'stat <398264>' /dev/sda2
debugfs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Inode: 398264   Type: regular    Mode:  0644   Flags: 0x80000
Generation: 2058737571    Version: 0x00000000:00000001
User:     0   Group:     0   Size: 562
File ACL: 0    Directory ACL: 0
Links: 1   Blockcount: 8
Fragment:  Address: 0    Number: 0    Size: 0
 ctime: 0x506b860b:19fa3c34 -- Wed Oct  3 02:25:47 2012
 atime: 0x50476677:dcd84978 -- Wed Sep  5 16:49:27 2012
 mtime: 0x506b860b:19fa3c34 -- Wed Oct  3 02:25:47 2012
crtime: 0x50476677:dcd84978 -- Wed Sep  5 16:49:27 2012
Size of extra inode fields: 28
EXTENTS:
(0):3308774
```

Time fields meaning:

- `ctime`: file change time.
- `atime`: file access time.
- `mtime`: file modification time.
- `crtime`: file creation time.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Linus' reply on LKML [thread](https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/7/22/249)</sub>

Comment: `sudo debugfs -R 'stat /path/to/foo' /dev/sda2` gives me `/path/to/foo: File not found by ext2_lookup`. `stat /path/to/foo` works (with Birth empty). Also, `ext2`?

Comment: @Sparhawk: I had this problem too with a file `/home/user/path/to/file` because `/home` was on a separate partition. In that case, the path provided to `stat` must be relative to `/home`. Example: `sudo debugfs -R 'stat user/path/to/file' /dev/sda2`. To get rid of the path handling, we can provide to `stat` the inode number instead of the path: `sudo debugfs -R "stat <$(stat -c %i /home/user/path/to/file)>" /dev/sda5`

Comment: Equivalent of `stat /home/richard` is `sudo debugfs -R 'stat /richard' /dev/disk/by-label/home` — assuming that `/home` is a separate file-system, and you file-systems are labelled.

Comment: @jpfleury My situation is like yours with a separation home partition. I can get the creation time by your method. But I don't know why. For example, home partition is sda5, and current directory is ~, and I want to get crtime of file.txt under ~. I use `sudo debugfs -R 'stat file.txt' /dev/sda5`. Why debufs cannot find the file.txt on sda5?

Comment: @Zachary: actually, I don't think the working directory of the terminal is used by debugfs. If you want to change the working directory of debugfs itself, you probably need to use its own `cd` command. I suppose its default working directory is the root of the filesystem accessed, so `/home` in your example. If your path `~` is `/home/zachary`, try `sudo debugfs -R 'stat /zachary/file.txt' /dev/sda5` or `sudo debugfs -R 'stat zachary/file.txt' /dev/sda5`. Both should work.

Comment: @Zachary: useful extract from the debugfs manual: `The filespec argument may be specified in two forms.  The first form is an inode number surrounded by angle brackets, e.g., <2>.  The second form is a pathname; if the pathname is pre‐fixed by a forward slash ('/'), then it is interpreted relative to the root of the filesystem which is currently opened by debugfs.  If not, the pathname is interpreted relative to the current working directory as maintained by debugfs.  This may be modified by using the debugfs command cd.`

Comment: @jpfleury Many thx. I see the point. The default `debugfs` **working directory** is the same as **root of the filesystem opened**. The `root /` is **NOT** the usual top directory of linux system, but the top directory of the partition (mine is sda5) debugged by debugfs.

Comment: Can this be used to get creation time of files from a network-mounted filesystem?

Comment: @taranaki - I don't think so

Comment: So this is not a time stamp that goes beyond the creation of the file system. It means that if a file was created 25 years ago and copied through lots of different physical or mounted systems, there is no way at all to find the information of the date of creation in any of the metadata? So the only way to know when a file was made is to type it into the file name? Or inside the content? Is there any reason for this seemingly odd non implementation?

Comment: @sinekonata file metadata is very system dependent (as this answer shows, every layer of the OS must be able to process it) and keeping it across copies between machines relies on the support for that metadata format by both systems *and* the copying tool. What this means is: you're lucky if you even get the file name non-mangled. 

Alternatively, some file formats allow you to insert metadata *inside* the file (e.g. [ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3)), and that generally carries well, but many formats don't have such feature. Finally, you can put the file inside an archive file like

Comment: Note that the `<` and `>` around the inode number are required. They are often used in examples to surround a variable that should be adjusted, but in this case they must be entered literally. Without them, the inode number is treated as a path, and you get a `File not found by ext2_lookup` error.

Answer (score 48):

I combined this into a simple shell function:

```bsh
get_crtime() {
  for target in "${@}"; do
    inode=$(stat -c %i "${target}")
    fs=$(df  --output=source "${target}"  | tail -1)
    crtime=$(sudo debugfs -R 'stat <'"${inode}"'>' "${fs}" 2>/dev/null | 
    grep -oP 'crtime.*--\s*\K.*')
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "${target}" "${crtime}"
  done
    }
```

You can then run it with

```
$ get_crtime foo foo/file /etc/
foo Wed May 21 17:11:08 2014
foo/file    Wed May 21 17:11:27 2014
/etc/   Wed Aug  1 20:42:03 2012
```

Comment: it didn't work for me on my raspbian jessie.

Comment: @sergius yes, rapsbian does something strange and makes `df` return `/dev/root` which doesn't actually exist. I don't know what it's doing, but you might want to ask a new question about why `df $HOME` returns `/dev/root` on raspbian. That's what is making this fail. For more info on `/dev/root` see: [Why on some Linux systems, does the root filesystem appear as /dev/root instead of /dev/in mtab?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/295060)

Comment: yes, you're right. The correct path is /dev/mmcblk0p2 for raspbian (on a raspberry, of course). Thanks, i'll try to be more specific over this.

Comment: It would be convenient if you prefix `sudo` to all commands, because sometimes the target files can not be accessed under current user.

Comment: @osexp2003 so run the function with sudo. No need to add it to every command.

Comment: @terdon `sudo get_crtime FILES` does not work because `get_crtime` is defined in current user's bash not the root user's bash, unless I put it to root users' .bashrc etc, that would be a hassle for just a quick try(copy and paste the function to terminal then run sudo get_crtime ...)

Comment: @osexp2003 oh duh, of course! I shouldn't answer comments before coffee, sorry. I that case though, I would just add this to root's configuration files. I don't want to run commands with sudo when it isn't absolutely needed since that adds unnecessary risk.

Comment: @terdon no problem. I understand the least privilege rule, so I am fine to keep existing code.

Answer (score 34):

The `xstat` function never got merged into mainline. However, a new [`statx` call was proposed later on](https://lwn.net/Articles/686106/), and was [merged in Linux 4.11](https://lwn.net/Articles/718222/). The new [`statx(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html) system call does include a creation time in its return struct. A wrapper for `statx(2)` was added to glibc only in [2.28 (release August 2018)](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2018-08/msg00003.html). And support for using this wrapper was added in [GNU coreutils 8.31](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2019-03/msg00003.html) (released March 2019):

> stat now prints file creation time when supported by the file system,
>     on GNU Linux systems with glibc >= 2.28 and kernel >= 4.11.

```
% stat --version
stat (GNU coreutils) 8.31
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Michael Meskes.
% stat /
  File: /
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: b302h/45826d    Inode: 2           Links: 17
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-06-06 20:03:12.898725626 +0900
Modify: 2019-05-28 05:15:44.452651395 +0900
Change: 2019-05-28 05:15:44.452651395 +0900
 Birth: 2018-06-07 20:35:54.000000000 +0900
```

---

What follows is a demo of `statx` where userland has yet to catch up (older glibc or coreutils). It's not easy to call system calls directly in a C program. Typically glibc provides a wrapper that makes the job easy, but Luckily, @whotwagner wrote [a sample C program](https://github.com/whotwagner/statx-fun) that shows how to use the `statx(2)` system call on x86 and x86-64 systems. Its output is the same format as `stat`'s default, without any formatting options, but it's simple to modify it to print just the birth time. (If you have a new enough glibc, you won't  need this - you can use `statx` directly as described in [`man 2 statx`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html)).

First, clone it:

```
git clone https://github.com/whotwagner/statx-fun
```

You can compile the `statx.c` code, or, if you just want the birth time, create a `birth.c` in the cloned directory with the following code (which is a minimal version of `statx.c` printing just the creation timestamp including nanosecond precision):

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _ATFILE_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "statx.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>

// does not (yet) provide a wrapper for the statx() system call
#include <sys/syscall.h>

/* this code works ony with x86 and x86_64 */
#if __x86_64__
#define __NR_statx 332
#else
#define __NR_statx 383
#endif

#define statx(a,b,c,d,e) syscall(__NR_statx,(a),(b),(c),(d),(e))

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int dirfd = AT_FDCWD;
    int flags = AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW;
    unsigned int mask = STATX_ALL;
    struct statx stxbuf;
    long ret = 0;

    int opt = 0;

    while(( opt = getopt(argc, argv, "alfd")) != -1)
    {
        switch(opt) {
            case 'a':
                flags |= AT_NO_AUTOMOUNT;
                break;
            case 'l':
                flags &= ~AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW;
                break;
            case 'f':
                flags &= ~AT_STATX_SYNC_TYPE;
                flags |= AT_STATX_FORCE_SYNC;
                break;
            case 'd':
                flags &= ~AT_STATX_SYNC_TYPE;
                flags |= AT_STATX_DONT_SYNC;
                break;
            default:
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                break;
        }
    }

    if (optind >= argc) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (; optind < argc; optind++) {
        memset(&stxbuf, 0xbf, sizeof(stxbuf));
        ret = statx(dirfd, argv[optind], flags, mask, &stxbuf);
        if( ret < 0)
        {
            perror("statx");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        printf("%lld.%u\n", *&stxbuf.stx_btime.tv_sec, *&stxbuf.stx_btime.tv_nsec);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Then:

```
$ make birth
$ ./birth ./birth.c
1511793291.254337149
$ ./birth ./birth.c | xargs -I {} date -d @{}
Mon Nov 27 14:34:51 UTC 2017
```

In theory this should make the creation time accessible on more filesystems than just the ext* ones (`debugfs` is a tool for ext2/3/4 filesystems, and unusable on others). It did work for an XFS system, but not for NTFS and exfat. I guess the FUSE filesystems for those didn't include the creation time.

Answer (score 11):

As of version 8.31 of GNU coreutils, [`stat` “now prints file creation time when supported by the file system, on GNU Linux systems with glibc >= 2.28 and kernel >= 4.11.”](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=9394)

My OS (Ubuntu 20.04, which comes with Linux kernel 5.4.0-28 and GLIBC 2.31) only came with GNU coreutils 8.30, so I had to verify by [compiling version 8.32 of GNU coreutils from source](https://duntuk.com/how-upgrade-coreutils-latest-version-source?PageSpeed=noscript).

Output of `ls -l --time=birth --time-style=full-iso --no-group`:

```
$ ls -l --time=birth --time-style=full-iso --no-group
total 13477610
-rwxr--r-- 1 systemd-coredump 13801071714 2017-06-30 04:53:33.211517792 -0400  file
```

Output of `stat` on a btrfs file system:

```
$ stat file
  File: /mnt/btrfs/file
  Size: 13801071714 Blocks: 26955224   IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 33h/51d Inode: 4998        Links: 1
Access: (0744/-rwxr--r--)  Uid: (  999/systemd-coredump)   Gid: (  999/systemd-coredump)
Access: 2020-05-04 12:21:51.640487614 -0400
Modify: 2016-01-19 10:32:19.272000000 -0500
Change: 2017-06-30 04:55:14.910839537 -0400
 Birth: 2017-06-30 04:53:33.211517792 -0400
```

(Strangely, I was unable to get any birth time to show on Arch Linux using a dummy ext4 file system, despite it having met all the above requirements.)

---

OLD ANSWER:

Well, [as of version 8.32 of GNU coreutils](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=9693) (stable release), both `stat` and `ls` use the `statx` call.

`ls` will show the creation/birth time.

> ** New Features
>
> ls now supports the --time=birth option to display and sort by
>   file creation time, where available.

And presumably, `stat` will too.

> ** Improvements
>
> stat and ls now use the statx() system call where available, which
>   can   operate more efficiently by only retrieving requested
>   attributes.

It’s brand-spanking new, having been posted just March 5, 2020, so it may take a while to trickle down unless you’re using a bleeding-edge distro like Arch Linux. (Arch Linux got version 8.32-1 of the [coreutils](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/coreutils/) package on April 1, 2020).

Comment: `stat` itself has been showing the creation date sine 8.31

Comment: I just got Ubuntu 20.04 up and running on my system. Unfortunately, it has version 8.30 of coreutils and that doesn’t show birth time, so I’m at least sure of 8.30 not having the functionality. EDIT: seems to have been described here https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=9394 And apparently it was a year ago.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407305/70524

Answer (score 9):

There's another case where Birth time will be empty/zero/dash: Ext4's Inode size has to be at least 256bytes to store `crtime`. The problem occur if you **initially created** the filesystem smaller than 512MB ( the default Inode size will be 128 bytes, see `/etc/mke2fs.conf` and `mkfs.ext4` manpage).

```
stat -c '%n: %w' testfile
testfile: -
```

and/or

```
stat -c '%n: %W' testfile
testfile: 0
```

Now check the filesystem inode (is it big enough to store `crtime`?):

```
tune2fs -l $(df . --output=source | grep ^/) | grep "Inode size:"
Inode size:           128
```

Technical information: On the [Ext4 Disk Layout](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inode_Table) page, note that some attributes of the inode tables are beyond 0x80 (128).

Comment: Correct (I remember reading about this on _vger_). The 512MB limit is defined in `mke2fs.c` at line [1275](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/misc/mke2fs.c#n1275)

Comment: I thought I was getting crazy - my boot partition is missing `crtime`. Thanks to your answer I know understand what's going on. I've tried to change the inode size using, `tune2fs -I 256 /dev/DEVICE` but it failed with `Changing the inode size not supported for filesystems with the flex_bg feature enabled`. Darn.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth I was feeling pedantic so wrote a bash wrapper around stat to silently support crtime using debugfs to fetch it from an underlying ext4 filesystem if available. I hope it's robust. [Find it here](https://github.com/bernd-wechner/Linux-Tools/blob/master/xstat).

Note that a fix is ostensibly on the todo list for Linux as documented in that script. So this wrapper has a nominal lifespan only until that is done and is more an exercise in what's doable.

Comment: Note that `xstat()` has eventually been added to Linux, so it's only a matter of time before the GNU libc and `find` add support for it.

Comment: Awesome! Good news indeed.

Comment: I am very late to the party but I just stumbled across this answer.  I have got your code but my filename starts with a $ sign e.g. $ncomdtl.dbf when i try your code on this file i get the following stat: cannot stat `/media/pcontrol/.dbf': No such file or directory

Comment: Totally credible that the script fails with a $ in the filename. Common bug. Would need to check it, as $ is of course a special chart in bash, and so needs escaping or the string in single quotes etc. Easy to diagnose and fix and PR is welcome, or I can check it when time permits (which is scant).