# How to find what device a file is on (and use that in a script)?

Tags: shell, files, sed, awk

I want to find out what device my file is on so that I can use it in a script. I can get this far:

```
$ df  .
Filesystem   512-blocks      Used Available Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2  498438976 294369520 203557456    60%    /
```

but this output feels too clumsy; is there a better way than parsing this to get the first 'word' of the second line?

What I really need is something like this so I can pipe it to the next command:

```
$ somecommand .
/dev/disk0s2
```

How can I achieve this, preferably without resorting to string hacking the 'df' output?

Comment: Parsing the `df` output is not difficult: `df . | tail -1 | cut -f 1 -d " "` But maybe there are better solutions.

Comment: Nice, this works. I'm running it on 10'000s of files, so I will have to see what the performance is like VS just one pipe

Comment: ... the other way is to use `stat`, which gives a device field, but you'll have to translate that back. May be *much* faster though, especially if `df` is taking forever to get usage over, e.g., NFS.

Comment: `stat -f "%Sdf" .` seems quicker - it decreased the time from 1.8s to 1.7 over 500 iterations. I have no network concerns, but this is a top tip, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the shell alone (works in `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`):

```
df . | (read a; read a b; echo "$a")
```

Or if output is not needed (result will be kept in $a) and your shell supports process substitution (like `bash`, `zsh`):

```
{ read; read a b;}< <(df .)
```

And here are some comparisons with the other solutions' speed:

```
# pure shell solution 1

bash-4.2$ time for i in $(seq 500); do df . | (read a; read a b; echo "$a"); done > /dev/null
1.899

(dash) $ time -f '%e' dash -c 'for i in $(seq 500); do df . | (read a; read a b; echo "$a"); done > /dev/null'
1.05

(ksh) $ time for i in $(seq 500); do df . | (read a; read a b; echo "$a"); done > /dev/null
    0m1.16s real     0m0.02s user     0m0.12s system

(zsh) manatwork% time (for i in $(seq 500); do df . | (read a; read a b; echo "$a"); done > /dev/null)
1.51s

# pure shell solution 2

bash-4.2$ time for i in $(seq 500); do { read; read a b;}< <(df .); done
1.192

(zsh) manatwork% time (for i in $(seq 500); do { read; read a b;}< <(df .); done)
3.51s

# other solutions

bash-4.2$ time for i in $(seq 500); do df . | tail -1 | cut -f 1 -d " "; done > /dev/null
1.405

bash-4.2$ time for i in $(seq 500); do df . | sed '2!d' | awk '{print $1}'; done > /dev/null
5.407

bash-4.2$ time for i in $(seq 500); do df . | sed -n '2{s/ .*$//;p}'; done > /dev/null
1.767

bash-4.2$ time for i in $(seq 500); do df . | sed '2!d' | awk '{print $1}'; done > /dev/null
3.334

bash-4.2$ time for i in $(seq 500); do df . | gawk 'NR==2{print $1}'; done > /dev/null
3.013

bash-4.2$ time for i in $(seq 500); do df . | mawk 'NR==2{print $1}'; done > /dev/null
1.747

bash-4.2$ time for i in $(seq 500); do df . | perl -nae 'print$F[0]if$.==2'; done > /dev/null
2.752
```

(Not compared with the `stat` solution as it not works here.)

Comment: All good; I love that there's so many ways to do this, and it's interesting to see how the time changes between awk, mawk, and gawk. What a great reference for this, thanks for taking the time to benchmark them too!

Answer (score 4):

It's the usual [way on UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#McIlroy%3a_A_Quarter_Century_of_Unix) to concatenate the powers of simple programs that to just a little. Hence don't worry to pipe the output of `df` through some filter.

```
df /path/to/file | sed -n '2{s/ .*$//;p}'
```

`-n` suppresses printing lines automatically, `2{}` executes the enclosed commands on second line, `s/ .*$//` discards everything from the first space, `p` prints what's left. Adding `q` after the `p` in cases when one parses longer input and just wants the second (or n-th) line could speed it up a bit too.

Comment: This didn't work for me: sed: 1: "2{s/ .*$//;p}": extra characters at the end of p command

Comment: Unix `sed`s are picky on missing `;`s. Try to add one after the `p` command. If still not works, specify what kind of `sed` are you using.

Comment: BSD sed, as found on OSX 10.7 - `df . | sed -n '2{s/ .*$//;p;}'` - this works

Comment: This seems to be faster than `tail | cut` and `sed|awk`.

Comment: Quite right, here's my timings;  
  
    time for i in {1..500}; do df . | sed -n '2{s/ .*$//;p;}'; done  
    real 0m1.587s  
    user 0m0.472s  
    sys 0m1.180s  
  
    time for i in {1..500}; do df . | sed '2!d' | awk '{print $1}'; done  
    real 0m2.484s  
    user 0m0.722s  
    sys 0m1.833s  
   
    time for i in {1..500}; do df . | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'; done  
    real 0m2.267s  
    user 0m0.672s  
    sys 0m1.701s  
  
I just need to work out how to do this one more way then I'll be happy. `awk`?

Comment: @jofel it should be - only one pipe (i.e. process spawning) + `sed` has quite small footprint even when compared to `awk`.

Comment: It is the usual UNIX way if there is no single command to do it. As @derobert commented you can just use `stat -f "%Sdf"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple one-line with `sed`, `awk` as

```
df . | sed '2!d' | awk '{print $1}'
```

In `sed`, specifying `2d` mean delete the 2<sup>nd</sup> line. Adding a `!` negate this, so it just deletes all other lines, and prints the 2nd line. The `awk` command then displays the first column value.

**Output:**

```
/dev/disk0s2
```

Comment: Why both `sed` and `awk`? Either is enough.

Comment: Nothing specific. I looked at it as more readable myself :)

Comment: what do the options on sed mean? I can guess that 2 means second line, but the rest is cryptic to me.

Comment: "2!" apply to everything except the second line: "d": delete

Comment: Thanks @jofel. -- @manatwork how would you do this with just `awk`? @peterph has already given an answer with just `sed`.

Comment: @antonyh: `df . | awk 'NR==2{print $1}'`

Comment: @manatwork thanks, I like this best - simple to read and fast. Please post it up as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the output of `df` is the best you can do portably. Pass `-P` to `df` to avoid it formatting the output in a weird way (you're probably safe everywhere since you're grabbing the first field, but you do need `-P` to grab the mount point as it may be relegated to a subsequent line if preceding columns are too wide).

```
device_name=$(df -P . | awk 'NR==2 {print $1}')
```

Note that some systems allow device names to contain whitespace (IIRC that tends to happen on OSX). There's no portable or convenient way to handle this case.

I don't think there's a better way to do this under Linux. `stat` can give you the device number (`stat -c %t .`), but if you want a device entry under `/dev`, you have to extract it from `/proc`, which `df` is better at doing.

Comment: On OSX the -P option forces 512-byte blocks and has nothing to do with formatting. `stat -f %Sdr .` gives me the device name without the `/dev/` prefix so it's close but I don't want to make assumptions that the device isn't in a sub-directory.

Comment: @antonyh `-P` is for POSIX compatibility. This includes both using 512-byte blocks and not splitting lines. The output of `stat -f %Sdr` is relative to `/dev`, you can safely use that on *BSD/OSX.

Comment: my apologies; this isn't mentioned in the man page, only the 512-byteness of the output for `-P` is in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using linux, you can do it with `findmnt` (part of `util-linux` package) *"without resorting to string hacking"*:

```
findmnt -no source -T /path/to/file
```

```
/dev/sda1
```

When using the option

```
-T, --target path
```

if the path is not a mountpoint file or directory, `findmnt` checks  path  elements in reverse order to get the mountpoint. The other two options suppress the header line: `-n, --noheading` and select the column(s) to be listed: `-o, --output`

---

`df` from `coreutils` has a similar option `--output=` to print only certain fields, like `source` e.g.:

```
df --output=source /path/to/file
```

```
Filesystem
/dev/sda1
```

there's no option to remove the header though. If that is a problem you'll have to do some minimal *string hacking* e.g. pipe it to `sed 1d`

Answer (score 0):

Note that none of the above solutions will work, if you are using `ecryptfs`.

However, the solution is simple: Just re-call the commands with the output as an argument, i.e.:

- `findmnt -no source -T "$(findmnt -no source -T /path/to/file)"`
- `df "$(df . | awk 'NR==2{print $1}')" | awk 'NR==2{print $1}'`

---

*Unfortunately `df . | sed '2!d' | awk '{print $1}'` will not work at all.*

```
$ df "$(df . | sed '2!d' | awk '{print $1}')" | sed '2!d' | awk '{print $1}'
bash: !d': event not found
```

First, bash will try to interpret `!` inside double-quotes as a history expansion (doesn't matter that inside command substitution it's inside single quotes), then escaping it ...

```
$  df "$(df . | sed '2\!d' | awk '{print $1}')" | sed '2!d' | awk '{print $1}'
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `\'
```

... will make `sed` complain about it (because `\` is inside single quotes inside the command substitution, so it's literal and **not** replaced with simply `!`)

You could still manually do it, though.