# Find the time of the file received in a particular directory

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

I have a directory called `/home/mydir/test`
A file will be sent from some other team which lands in this directory. How to find what is the time the file came to this particular directory? ( I need both time in time stamp format and normal hh:mm:ss format too ) I have to move the files to directory which is here for more than 5 hours. How to fetch  those files?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us i) why the timestamp from `ls -l file` is not enough; ii) if that is not enough, explain how the file is being copied and iii) the filesystem you are using.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Do you need to know the time it arrived so that you know it's a "new" file and needs to be processed? If so, please say so because there are better ways of identifying when a file has arrived in a directory (`inotifywait` for one).

Comment: I need the time of file arrival in order to do check for the files which are in the directory for more than 4 hours

Comment: Why not use find then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `stat -c %w filename`, it will provide the date of birth in human readable way, and `-C` will provide in unix timestamp.

Time of birth is not supported on every filesystem; use `stat -c %z`, i.e. time of last change, in those cases.

Comment: I have modified the question , How to get the files which are there in this folder for more than 5 hours

Comment: How can I compare with today's date with the value i get from stat -c %z filename and get the difference in a variable

Answer (score 1):

stat without options allows you to see all timestamps (birth,access,modify,change)

Comment: On what file system do you see birth?

Comment: ext4 i think or ext3

Comment: which kind of time i should use for this scenario?

Comment: i think it is displayed with debug flag on stat: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50177/birth-is-empty-on-ext4

Answer (score 1):

For the last part of your question: Use `find` to find  all files older than 5 * 60 minutes (`-cmin` tests for change time in minutes, `+300` means more than 300); `{}` is replaced with the filename:

```
find in_dir -cmin +300 -type f -exec mv {} out_dir \;
```

**Update:** added `-type f` to not move in_dir itself to out_dir.