# Why does my file have multiple crtime entries?

Tags: ext4, timestamps, atime

Using `ext4` filesystem I was able to read out the creation time of a file using the [approach here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50184/24394). As a result I am indeed provided with a table featuring the `crtime` (creation time) of the inode(respective file) in question.

What confuses me and to which I could not find an answer in the `man debugfs` is why it shows me 2 lines with `crtime`, moreover not even being the same time.

This is the output I get

```
[user ~] $ sudo debugfs -R "stat <274742>" /dev/sda2
debugfs 1.43.1 (08-Jun-2016)
Inode: 274742   Type: regular    Mode:  0644   Flags: 0x80000
Generation: 3666549610    Version: 0x00000000:00000001
User:  1000   Group:  1000   Project:     0   Size: 0
File ACL: 0    Directory ACL: 0
Links: 0   Blockcount: 0
Fragment:  Address: 0    Number: 0    Size: 0
 ctime: 0x57b4c632:1e30ee34 -- Wed Aug 17 22:16:50 2016
 atime: 0x57b4c4c0:afa082b0 -- Wed Aug 17 22:10:40 2016
 mtime: 0x57b4c632:1e30ee34 -- Wed Aug 17 22:16:50 2016
crtime: 0x57b4c4c0:afa082b0 -- Wed Aug 17 22:10:40 2016
crtime: 0x57b4c632:(1e30ee34) -- Wed Aug 17 22:16:50 2016
Size of extra inode fields: 32
```

Also note that the second (and not realy correct) `crtime` is in brackets and equals the `mtime`, since I saved to the file obviously twice.

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/debugfs/debugfs.c?h=v1.43.1#n890), it looks like a copy/paste error. The second `crtime` ought to be `dtime`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Hmm on CentOS 7 it correctly reports `dtime`; maybe that's a RedHat patch :-)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes that was it. Liked the linked the source code reference. if you moved that to an answer it was possible to resolve this question more obviously..

Comment: @StephenHarris CentOS 7 has a version of e2fsprogs (1.42.9) that preceeds the change that introduced the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the result of an editing error in the e2fsprogs patch [debugfs: add support to properly set and display extended timestamps](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/commit/debugfs/debugfs.c?h=v1.43.1&id=188960ea4b830ec69607aab3068537ce55f44be4). The second **crtime:** line ought to be **dtime:**.

```
if (inode->i_dtime)
  fprintf(out, "%scrtime: 0x%08x:(%08x) -- %s", prefix,
          large_inode->i_dtime, large_inode->i_ctime_extra,
          inode_time_to_string(inode->i_dtime,
          large_inode->i_ctime_extra));
```

I submitted a bug report.

Comment: great to hear that there was a bug report filed. what keeps me yet a little suprised is that **dtime** would be (delete) time appeared. Seems that my program (geany editor) did indeed delete and replace the file, so that when I checked with the old inode I was shown the dtime (confusingly mislabeled crtime)