# Is there still no Linux kernel interface to get file creation date?

Tags: filesystems, stat

For a long time, Linux hasn't bothered with file creation dates because none of the file systems it commonly used supported them.  However now, 2 file systems commonly used (NTFS and ext4) both record file creation dates.

The `stat` command, however, still outputs `Birth: -` on an ext4 file system, even though we can see that ext4 has stored the file's create date using `debugfs -R 'stat <inode_number>' /dev/file_device`.

When I looked into why this is, I saw that someone else has already [recently filed](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=793831) a bug report on it, and the response links through to an [upstream issue](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=14703) that simply states "there is no Linux kernel interface at present to get that info [file creation date]".  It seems remarkable to me that this is apparently *still* the case, as people have been requesting that `stat` display this info for years (and `stat` does output a `Birth` field, even though it apparently doesn't support it yet!  Did they add it in anticipation?)

So is it still true that there is no Linux kernel interface at present to get file creation date?  Is there a plan to implement this ever?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/703927/38062 for some background.  And enjoy http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304245/5132 when you are using `debugfs`.

Comment: Yay!  Only 6 years for Linus to approve :-)

Comment: `ZFS` also records file creation time and allows them to be retrieved via extended attributes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EDIT: Good news, `statx()` has been merged so it should be available in release 4.11.

- https://lwn.net/Articles/716302/
- https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=a528d35e8bfcc521d7cb70aaf03e1bd296c8493f

---

xstat() work, currently statx(), was revised in 2016.

- http://lwn.net/Articles/685791/
- http://lwn.net/Articles/686106/

The process was a bit more disciplined this time (less bikeshedding, agreement to drop controversial attributes as they can always be added later).  Unfortunately there were still objections to the exact interface and I haven't seen any more recent references.

Comment: The article you linked to isn't available without a subscription.  Is it this email?  https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/3/5/149  If so link to that, it's free.

Comment: @Jez fixed.  LWN link will become available 7 days later.

Comment: I am running kernel 4.11.2 on Xubuntu 17.04 with latest coreutils (8.27.37-02b65a-dirty) compiled from git source. stat still reports empty birth time. What's wrong?

Comment: @shrx: Glibc didn't support xstat until 2.28 so perhaps that was the problem in May 2017?

Answer (score 4):

> because none of the file systems it commonly used supported them

From what I can tell (sorry a bunch of links, memory, and googlage, nothing cohesive enough to list here as a reference), it was never because the underlining systems didn't support creation time attributes, but because none of them could even agree that it was a useful feature.

See http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html

POSIX lays out three time stamps. None of them are creation time.

If I remember correctly the argument went something like:

```
> Give me a use case where we can't already do that using what we already have.
< Some examples were submitted
> All of these are convoluted beyond usefulness. 
> Ok, Ok, *maybe* a couple of these don't suck. 
> Now how do you see handling file systems that don't track this?
< several ideas that were not the same. 
< Basically everyone had a special case that would work, but not 
< one that always works. Fight about fallbacks and other special handling. 
> Ok, lets table that for now. What should we call this field
< At least 6 different answers emerged.
> So, you want to break POSIX standards, 
> you can't really come up with a good reason why, 
> you can't come up with a good fall back, and 
> you can't even come up with a name. 
> Sounds like it's specific to the file system to me, and that 
> should be "extended data" accessible by tools and not as 
> a core stat in the Kernel.
```

Now a lot of this is memory and reading some old mailing lists. I didn't really sit central to arguments either. I was on a mailing list because of some off shoot work in a fat driver for an embedded Linux system. I mention that because there are surely more authoritative sources then my memory of something I only kinda cared about.

I do remember the big deal being a combination of the fact that no one could come up with a good use case, no one could agree on how to handle the field for the other 40 commonly used file systems that don't support creation time, and even coming up with a name for the field turned into a massive debate.

Comment: Keep in mind that creation time in file systems that support it have *always* been accessible as an extended stat. It's just that implementation for getting those extended stats vary quite a bit, so there not in tools like ls or find. Argument being is that ls would have to know details of the file system to get the info and that's not what ls is about.

Comment: using something like `debugfs` to read the field off the disk image isn't much of an _interface_, and it's going to need privileged access anyway.

Comment: Seems like the arguments were because the place to actually change this before implimentation should be consider is in POSIX itself. :)

Answer (score 3):

The birth time is in several Linux native file systems, not only ext4¹.

[Since version 4.11 of the Linux kernel](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.11#statx.282.29.2C_a_modern_stat.282.29_alternative) (April 2017), there's a new [`statx()` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html) to retrieve it. However, the corresponding  wrapper function has not been added to the GNU libc yet (as of 2018-06-26. **2019 edit** now added in 2.28), and tools like GNU `stat`, `ls`, `find` have not been updated to use it (**2019-08-22 edit** GNU `stat` on GNU/Linux systems with glibc 2.28 or above supports it since coreutils 8.31; **2021-01-04 edit** and GNU `ls` has a `--time=birth` since coreutils 8.32)

You could do it in `perl` though with something like:

```
perl -MPOSIX -e '
  require "syscall.ph";
  $buf = "\0" x 0x100; # enough space for a struct statx
  for (@ARGV) {
    # hardcode: AT_FDCWD == -100
    #           AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW = 0x100 (lstat()-like)
    #           STATX_BTIME = 0x800 for the mask
    #           80: offset of the btime in the struct
    syscall(&SYS_statx, -100, $_, 0x100, 0x800, $buf) == 0
      or die "$_: $!\n";
    ($t, $n) = unpack("x80QQ", $buf);
    $n = sprintf("%09d", $n);
    print strftime("%F %T.$n %z\n", localtime $t)
  }' -- "$file"
```

If your `syscall.ph` doesn't have `SYS_statx`, you could hardcode it as well. It's 332 on amd64 architectures. Or try:

```
printf '#include <syscall.h>\n__NR_statx\n' | gcc -E -xc - | tail -n 1
```

Now that birth time is rarely useful. It's not the age of the data in the file (data is written to files *after* they have been created), nor necessarily the time the file appeared by that name in a directory (it could have been created as a different name and renamed or linked there and the content or attributes been changed several times in between).

---

<sup>¹ as a special case, with ext4, if the file system has been created with an inode size of 128 bytes, the birth time field is not included.</sup>

Comment: If Linux did fully support `NFSv4`it would need to support extended attributes and there is a possible entry `crtime` in the extended attributes. Check e.g. the Solaris `ls.c` source that prints the file creation time with `ls -l -% crtime`.

Comment: @schily, Linux has extended attributes and ntfs-3g as typically used on opensource OSes like Linux does indeed expose the NTFS creation time as an extended attribute, though since 4.11, I'd expect it's also available through `statx()`. There's no standard utility which interface to `statx()` yet on Linux, but retrieving extended attributes has been supported for decades. See [How do I get the creation date of a file on an NTFS logical volume?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/87265)

Comment: Well Linux extended attributes are modeled after a POSIX draft that has been withdrawn in 1997. NFSv4 defines a modern extended attribute system, that allows to support NTFS file streams as a subset and that is accessed via the file's attribute directory that is opened via `openat(fd, ".", O_RDONLY|O_XATTR)`.

Comment: @schily, you're confusing with ACLs here. Indeed, Linux has no support for NFSv4 ACLs yet except with an unofficial patch but that has little to do with extended attributes (except that the ACLs would be typically stored as extended attributes). Linux does support extended attributes, which it does indeed use for those  POSIX-draft-type ACLs, and for a number of other things. And the API to retrieve those attributes is also used by ntfs-3g to expose the crtime, I suppose in a similar way as on Solaris.

Comment: @schily, looks like [you've added misinformation to Wikipedia on that](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Extended_file_attributes&diff=702087069&oldid=702073319). Please fix.

Comment: You are confusing ACLs, Xattrs and POSIX.1e, please inform yourself.... The withdrawn POSIX.1e presented a concept for ACLs and Xattrs and both has been withdrawn. The withdrawn ACL draft on the other side did never require to be implemented inside xattrs. See the first UNIX ACL implementation from 1993 on Solaris that was used as the model for the withdrawn POSIX:1e draft. The Solaris ACL implementations base on shadow inodes. My statement on Wikipedia of course is correct.

Comment: It would be nice if you did remove your wrong statement about missinformation on Wikipedia..

Comment: @schily, extended attribute support was added to Linux in 2.5.3 (January 2002) and had little to do with that POSIX.1e draft. There are  just generic extended file attributes like in most other OSes. The POSIX.1e ACLs were added in 2.5.46 in November 2002 as they were a more or less de-facto standard even if POSIX had given up making it an official standard at the time. I'd still say your statement there is misleading and out of place.

Comment: `star` impemented ACL support for Linux in November 2001, so you are wrong again. At that time, everybody had already agreed in using the `NTFS` based ACLs in the future.

Comment: @schily, before 2.5.46, those ACLs were only available as part of an unofficial patch. Linus notoriously objected to added ACLs to Linux which probably explained why they were added to the official kernel long after the extended attributes that supported them. So I suppose your `star`  was working with that patch.

Comment: 2001 is long ago, I don't remember anymore. What I remember is that I created a draft implementation for Solaris and soon received a patch for Linux. Today, `star` supports the withdrawn ACLs on Solaris, AIX, IRIX, FreeBSD and Linux and the `NFSv4 ACLs` on Solaris and FreeBSD, while GNU tar just supports the withdrawn ACLs on Linux and even may install ACLs that are not in the archive.