# Why is time of birth of file unknown?

Tags: filesystems, timestamps, stat

Command `stat -c%w /home/knezi/file` returns just dash. It means, according to the documentation, that the date of birth in unknown. I've tried plenty of files but all with the same result.

The question is: do I need to turn on timestamping of filesystem (note that last access and modification work)? Or what else could possibly be the problem?

I'm running Arch Linux - 64b, FS ext4 (tried also on tmpfs).

Comment: It's stored on some filesystems (not all). But there's no real interface to get it from the kernel. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7562/170373 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/304779/170373

Comment: Thank you replies. It is probably duplicate. I just don't have crtime installed on my machine. Is it in some non-standard package?