# How to rename multiple files with the time created?

Tags: linux, rename, timestamps

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *.png
do
    echo mv -n "$f" "$(date +%Y%m%d-%H-%M-%S)_$f"
done
```

I want to rename several files with their timestamp as stated in (`ls -lt --full-time`), but I run when my code above, the name uses the current date/time or modify time. I want the year, month, and day in yymmdd format.

Answer (score 7):

Just use the `-r` option of GNU `date` which reports the date corresponding to the last modification time of the file after symlink resolution (like `ls -Ll` does)

```
#!/bin/sh -
for f in *.png
do
  t=$(date -r "$f" +%Y%m%d-%H-%M-%S) &&
    echo mv -n -- "$f" "${t}_$f"
done
```

Or use `zsh` which has a `stat`  builtin to format the time in any format:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/stat || exit

for f (*.png(N))
  stat -A t -F %Y%m%d-%H-%M-%S +mtime -- $f &&
    print -r mv -n -- $f ${t}_$f
```

Note that some systems including GNU and BSDs have added (much later¹) their own `stat` command though with completely different APIs (from zsh's and between each other).

`exiftool` can also rename any file based on any of its attributes:

```
exiftool -d %Y%m%d-%H-%M-%S '-FileName<${FileModifyDate}_${FileName}' -- *.png
```

Note that all those and your `ls -lt --full-time` (which should probably have an extra `-L` in case some of those png files are symlinks) look at the  last modification time of the file. That can be considered as the creation time of the contents of the file which generally is what you care for. Files on Linux also have what is called a *birth time* aka *creation time* which reflects when the file  spawned into existence (but has little to do with when the  contents was created).

With recent versions of GNU `ls` with a recent kernel and GNU libc (so not on CentOS), you can retrieve that with `ls --time=birth -Ll --full-time`, and with recent versions of GNU `stat` with `stat -Lc %w`, but none of `date`, zsh `stat` nor `exiftool` can retrieve that as the API to do so is very recent and Linux-specific. And that timestamp is generally not useful. See [When was file created](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119698) or [Is there still no Linux kernel interface to get file creation date?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/304779) for details.

---

<sup>¹ Though note that early Unix versions did have a `stat` command. For some reason it seemed to have disappeared in the mid-70s as research Unix v6 no longer had one.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You should use `stat` command to get the file date. I don't know if you want to get the creation date (birth) or the modification date of the file. I will provide an example using both dates.

**Using birth date**

```bash
#!/bin/sh
for f in *.png
do
    cdate=$(stat -c '%w'  "$f" | cut -d ' ' -f1)
    echo mv -n "$f" "${cdate}_$f"
done
```

**Using modification date**

```bash
#!/bin/sh
for f in *.png
do
    mdate=$(stat -c '%y'  "$f" | cut -d ' ' -f1)
    echo mv -n "$f" "${mdate}_$f"
done
```

With `stat -c '%w' somefile` you get the creation/birth date and with `stat -c '%y' somefile` you get the modification date.

The code above will return the date in `YYYYMMDD` format, if you want to get only in `YYMMDD` format you can apply parameter expansion (I'm not sure if this one is supported by POSIX or `sh`). Here you are another example (using bash):

**Using birth date**

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.png
do
    cdate=$(stat --printf='%.10w\n' "$f")
    echo mv -n "$f" "${cdate#??}_$f"
done
```

**Using modification date**

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.png
do
    mdate=$(stat --printf='%.10y\n' "$f")
    echo mv -n "$f" "${mdate#??}_$f"
done
```

With `stat --printf='%.10w\n'` or `stat --printf='%.10y\n'` I'm getting the first ten characters of the string that will represent the date in `YYYYMMDD` format. With `${cdate#??}` or `${mdate#??}` I'm removing the first two digits of the date so I will get this one in `YYMMDD` format.