# Is ctime of find the creation time?

Tags: files, find, timestamps

In the man of `find` the `-ctime` is said to be :

```
-ctime n 
          File status was last changed n*24 hours ago.  See the comments
          for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation
          of file status change times.

-atime n
          File  was  last  accessed n*24 hours ago.  When find figures out
          how many 24-hour periods ago the file  was  last  accessed,  any
          fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to
          have been accessed at least two days ago.
```

I know from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/what-file-systems-on-linux-store-the-creation-time) that the `ext4` file system stores the creation date , and you can get it using `stats` , is the `status change times` they are talking about in the manual the same as the one given by `stats` ? or precisely , is the `ctime` the date of creation of a file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is the date of the last *status change* to the file, i.e. writes to file data or metadata.

## Further reading

- https://superuser.com/a/703927/38062
- [How to find creation date of file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/)
- [Is there still no Linux kernel interface to get file creation date?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304779/)
- [Why does my file have multiple crtime entries?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304067/)

Comment: i need to perform a find  of a files that have not been created in more then 30 days , so `-ctime +30` will not work ?

Comment: @Kingofkech If the files haven't been modified at all since creation, then it will.  If they have had permissions, ownership, name, or size changes (among other things), it won't.