# Get tar to save birth time

Tags: filesystems, tar

Is there anyway to make a `tar` archive that includes the creation times for the files/directories inside of it?

Comment: creation time is not readily accessible on linux (ext4 for eg.) even though the filesystem has this info.

Comment: @jai_s it is accessible now, see muru’s comment below.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible (outside the scope of `tar`) because the POSIX standard does not define a timestamp for file creation. Some filesystems (e.g. ext4, JFS, Btrfs) store this value, but currently there is no Linux kernel API to access it.

Timestamp values that are readily accessible on Linux are:

- `mtime` Time of last modification to file contents (data itself)
- `ctime` Time of last change to file contents or file metadata (owner, group, or permissions)
- `atime` Time of last access to file for reading contents

Comment: There's an API now: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407305/70524 (but I don't think modifying creation time is possible anyway)