# What does <$( )> do

Tags: bash, shell

I saw the syntax in this question: [Birth is empty on ext4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50177/birth-is-empty-on-ext4)

> ```
> sudo debugfs -R "stat <$(stat -c %i /home/user/path/to/file)>" /dev/sda5
> ```

I know command substitution `$()` and ``` `` ```.

I kind of vaguely know the `<()` and `>()` syntax.

But I've never seen `<$()>`.

So what does that do?

Comment: I think the `< >` is being passed to `debugfs`.

Comment: Quotes matter. `<$(...)>` would be shell syntax (not meaningful or valid, but shell syntax nonetheless) -- but inside double quotes, `<` and `>` are literal characters; the shell leaves them alone.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`<$()>` would be valid bash syntax for commands that read from a file
(`<` part) where file names are created using command substitution
(`$()` part) that redirect output to some other file (`>`
part). Example:

```
$ echo text > FILE
$ wc < "$(echo FILE)" > WC_OUT
$ cat WC_OUT
1 1 5
```

However, in the answer you linked to `<$()>` is used in the parameters
to `debugfs`. In `man debugfs` it says:

> stat filespec
>
> Display the contents of the inode structure of the inode filespec.

and:

> The filespec argument may be specified in two forms.  The first form
>   is an inode number surrounded by angle brackets, e.g., <2>

In that case:

```
sudo debugfs -R "stat <$(stat -c %i FILE)>" /dev/sda5
```

would be expanded by the shell to the equivalent of this:

```
sudo debugfs -R "stat <4476834>" /dev/sda5
```

which is a valid `debugfs` command. Check it with `echo`:

```
$ echo sudo debugfs -R "stat <$(stat -c %i FILE)>" /dev/sda5
sudo debugfs -R stat <4476834> /dev/sda5
```

Comment: My mind is blown, I didn't check the man page of `debugfs` since I assumed that no bash command would parse an argument as `<123456789>`.

Comment: Technically, `debugfs` is not Bash commad, that is it's not Bash built-in command. It's an external program that could run in all shells, even in these that do not implement `<` and `>` and on multiple operating systems.