# I need creation date and time of file in Linux

Tags: files, timestamps

I need to creation date and time of file in linux.

I have tried below two command but did not get any output.

1. `sudo debugfs -R 'stat <inode_no of file>' "mount point name"`.

   This gives me the following error:

   ```
   Bad magic number in super-block while opening the file system
   ```
2. `stat -c '%w' file_name`

This gives me `-` as output.

So someone please suggest appropriate command to get create date and time of file in linux.

Comment: Recording the creation time is not supported on all file systems. Please specify how the partition you are working on is formatted. If it is `ext4`, it is unfortunately impossible.

Comment: Some filesystems carry birth time (`btime` - creation date). Most do not, and you have to revert to modification time (`mtime`). If you're getting `-` from `stat -c %w` then it's probably your filesystem is one of those without birth time

Comment: What are you giving as "mount point name"? If you have `/dev/sda1` mounted at `/`, are you giving `/` or `/dev/sda1` as the name? And what file system are you using? Also see [Birth is empty on ext4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50184).

Comment: I am giving "mount point name" as /dev/sda1. And I am using xfs file system. So xfs file system is not supported creation or birth time of file in linux?

Comment: Wikipedia claims XFS supports crtime from Version 5. However, I searched the 369-page online RHEL Admin Guide for the terms *crtime* and *stamp* and *creation* and got nothing relevant. Wiki "comparison_of_file_systems" says XFS supports "Creation time stored since June 2015, xfsprogs version 3.2.3".

Comment: I have checked and found XFS file system version is 4.5 in my system. So XFS file system 4.5 version will not support creation date and time?

Comment: I have checked this in XFS version 5 file as well but getting same output.

Answer (score 4):

From the man page for `stat`:

```
%w     time of file birth, human-readable; - if unknown
```

Most file systems do not hold the "creation date" of files. The concept just does not exist. It is also fairly meaningless: you can create a file, and then change every single byte in it at any time without altering the creation date.

This is always available, and usually much more relevant.

```
%y     time of last data modification, human-readable
```

Comment: I want modification date and time of file as well which I got and If we change every single byte in it at any time without altering the creation date then I will not get modification date and time of file. So please provide suitable solution for this.

Comment: Changing any of the data (from a single bit to every byte) changes the modification timestamp. In fact, even writing zero-length data to a zero-length file changes the mod date (although appending zero bytes to a file does not). There **is** no creation date, and the system cannot modify something that does not exist.

Comment: I want modification and creation date and time of file but I I got modification date and time but not getting creation date and time of file. If we change every single byte in it at any time without altering the creation date then I will get the creation date and time but will not get modification date and time of file. So please provide proper solution to get the creation date and time of file.

Comment: @WakarKhan  I reiterate: `There is no creation date, and the system cannot modify something that does not exist.` If your file system reports the crtime as `-`, then get a different file system that **does** support crtime. But most likely, your dump/restore system will not retain the crtime either, so any file you recover will still not have the value.

Comment: Previously have checked in XFS file system and now have checked in ext4 file but system but getting same result.