# Showing the Creation date of a File

Tags: files, timestamps

I guess there's no way to get that under most Linux flavors, please correct me if I'm wrong.  My hack is to go up a directory level and get the info and the directory containing the file I'm interested in, and if it was the last one created, the modification time on the parent directory will tell me the creation time of the file I'm interested in.

Comment: It's been possible on Linux using the usual tools for about 4 years now: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407305/70524