# How to determine when KVM vm was created?

Tags: system-installation, kvm, stat

OS is Debian.

Not asking about uptime of course, but I would like to determine when vm was created and/or first booted.

Normally you can do something like: `stat /` and check birth time, but for a kvm vm it just shows "-". (I've seen this issue on bare metal systems as well sometimes, not sure why)

What is a foolproof way to check when a server was created? Is this even possible? Wondering about kvm vms, but would be interested in a solution for bare metal systems that for one reason or another show "-" for birth time.

Edit: I was assuming that KVM vms are created from images. I realize now that it's possible to create KVM vms from an installer, but for this question, assume image. Is this possible to determine in this case?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this?: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50177/birth-is-empty-on-ext4

Answer (score 0):

Your installation has the root filesystem set up using a filesystem type that does not track creation times.

On any Debian-based distribution, the OS installer will normally leave its logs at `/var/log/installer/`, and nothing generally touches them afterwards, so try:

```
ls -lt --full-time /var/log/installer/
```

With other distributions, if you can find a file that's created by the OS installer and not modified afterwards, you can use a similar command with it.

For example, on RHEL and related distributions, the installer will typically create a `/root/anaconda.ks` file at end of installation. If it is still present, its timestamp will identify the installation time, assuming the system clock had the correct time at the time of installation.