# Does "freshening" a zip file with the -FS option change the modification time of the file?

Tags: files, timestamps, zip

I have a zip file that I use as a backup for my work.  I use the "freshen" option (`-FS`) whenever I want to update my backup file.  However, the file shows the date of last modification as being the date I originally created the file, rather than any of the several times since I have "freshened" the file.  Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unix doesn't have a create date, so when you update these files in your `.zip` you're updating them based on their modification date, which according to the `zip` man page is normal behavior.

*excerpt*

```
The new File Sync option (-FS) is also considered a new mode, though it 
is similar to update.  This mode synchronizes the archive with the files on 
the OS, only replacing files in the archive if the file time or size of the 
OS file is different, adding new files, and deleting entries from the 
archive where there is no matching file.  As this mode can delete entries 
from  the  archive,  consider making a backup copy of the archive.
```

#### Example

Say we have the following 3 files:

```
$ touch file1 file2 file3
```

We add them to a ZIP file.

```
$ zip file.zip file{1..3}
  adding: file1 (stored 0%)
  adding: file2 (stored 0%)
  adding: file3 (stored 0%)
```

Some time passes and `file3` gets updated.

```
$ touch file3
```

Now we update the ZIP file.

```
$ zip -FS file.zip file{1..3}
updating: file3 (stored 0%)
```

Checking the ZIP file we see the times for the files is now like so:

```
$ unzip -l file.zip 
Archive:  file.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  07-12-2014 02:59   file1
        0  07-12-2014 02:59   file2
        0  07-12-2014 03:00   file3
---------                     -------
        0                     3 files
```

If we create a temporary directory and unpack the ZIP file within:

```
$ mkdir temp; cd temp

$ unzip ../file.zip 
Archive:  ../file.zip
 extracting: file1                   
 extracting: file2                   
 extracting: file3
```

The contents of this directory are as follows:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Jul 12 02:59 file1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Jul 12 02:59 file2
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Jul 12 03:00 file3
```

And if we use the `stat` command to check out `file3`:

```
$ stat file3
  File: ‘file3’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 17307675    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    saml)   Gid: ( 1000/    saml)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2014-07-12 03:00:16.000000000 -0400
Modify: 2014-07-12 03:00:16.000000000 -0400
Change: 2014-07-12 03:01:03.447913554 -0400
 Birth: -
```

**NOTE:** Notice there is timestamps for access, modify, and change. The `zip` command is preserving the access and modify times when you use the `-FS` switch.

#### References

- [get age of given file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102691/get-age-of-given-file/102692#102692)
- [How to find creation date of file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file)
- [Get file created/creation time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/get-file-created-creation-time)

Comment: So, `-FS` will update the timestamp of the individual files in the .zip file while the .zip file's own timestamp remains unchanged?

Comment: @Joshua - no it's not possible to preserve the timestamp of the .zip file itself. Anytime you manipulate it, you're modifying the timestamp.

Comment: I'm not asking because I want to preserve the timestamp, I'm asking because the timestamp of my `.zip` file does not update after I use the `-FS` flag.