# Linux file create time

Tags: command-line

I am searching a command that gives me the file create time in a folder.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/get-file-created-creation-time

Answer (score 0):

You can get information using the command `stat`

Example:

```
stat index.htm
```

==>

```
File: `index.htm'
Size: 17137 Blocks: 40 IO Block: 8192 regular file
Device: 8h/8d Inode: 23161443 Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--) 
Uid: (17433/comphope) Gid: ( 32/ www)
Access: 2007-04-03 09:20:18.000000000 -0600
Modify: 2007-04-01 23:13:05.000000000 -0600
Change: 2007-04-02 
16:36:21.000000000 -0600
```

Comment: where is the create date in this?

Comment: that's not create date is it?