# How to get no of lines and the data of the file created data in unix

Tags: shell-script, shell, wc

I have a file named as abc.txt and I am trying to extract no of records present in the file and the file creation date.

```
wc -l abc.txt
```

This is giving me only no of records in the file.

How to get the count and the data at a time in a single command?

Comment: Why do you believe that such a single command exists? See also [Get file created/creation time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/get-file-created-creation-time)

Comment: If instead of a single "command" you just want a single line, you can always string together different commands with the `&&` operator. For example `wc -l abc.txt && stat abc.txt`

Comment: What's this fascination with doing things in a single command or on a single line? I _really_ don't get it. Most operations done in multiple stages are unreadable if written on a single line, and as such, they are unmaintainable and should be avoided.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for the responses. I have around 1000 files and need to get the count and data of all the files into a single file. This is what I am trying to achieve