# Awk not rendering any result

Tags: shell-script, awk, ksh, quoting

My goal is to get the file created in the current month in a directory.

It seems that the command is correct but not rendering any result:

```
Date=`date '+%b'`

echo $Date
Oct

ls -l | awk -v d="$Date" '/d/ {print $NF}'
```

Comment: You have not explained what you really want. This is a broken code.

Comment: May be it's better to use `find` with `-mtime`?

Comment: @dchirikov Agreed, or even `-ctime` to catch when file attributes have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `awk` has no way of telling that the `d` inside the pattern is meant to represent the variable of that name: `awk` is trying to match a literal `d`. You can make use of parameter expansion instead:

```
ls -l | awk "/$Date/ {print \$NF}"
```

That said, two things to note:

- The time listed in `ls -l` output is the timestamp: the last time the file was modified, not created. File creation times are [unreliable at best](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/what-file-systems-on-linux-store-the-creation-time) and unavailable at worst.
- You [shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

  Use `find` instead, as in [dchirikov's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96120/26909).

Comment: `-v` tells awk to use environmental variable

Comment: @dchirikov As far as I know, `-v` is used to assign variables localized to `awk` not obtain variables from your current environment.

Comment: Right. Environment variables can be accessed through the `ENVIRON` array. So if you previously `export Date`, then `ls -l | awk '$0 ~ ENVIRON["Date"] {print $NF}'` will also work.

Comment: yep! `ENVIRON` of course. And `-v` is for shell variables.

Comment: @Ram Glad I helped. I believe dchirikov's answer was better though. Stay away from the output of `ls` unless you're parsing it with your eyes.

Comment: 1. Solutions using `ls` and `awk` mis-fire on files that contain the
   current month abbreviation in the name, e.g. "Octopus", "Nova",
   "Decimal", etc.
2. Solutions using `ls` and `awk` fail to print the full name of files that
   contain blanks or newlines in the name, e.g. "my file".
3. As has been said: do not [parse the output of
   ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Use `find`.

Answer (score 7):

You should use it this way:

```
ls -l | awk -v d="$Date" '$0 ~ d {print $NF}'
```

Explanation is [here](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html#SEC32)

But may be it's better to use `find` in your script.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -daystart -ctime -`date "+%d"`
```

If you have classic `awk` instead of `gawk`:

```
find * -prune -type f -cmin -`date '+%d %H %M' | awk '{print ($1*24+$2)*60+$3}'`
```

Comment: +1 I hope you don't mind, I edited your link so that it points directly to the relevant section instead of the TOC.

Comment: Since I am using AIX 6.1 machine the flags such as -maxdepth and -daystart are not available.

Comment: Ok. I've added an update. Hope it helps.