# How to check XFS filesystem version?

Tags: linux, xfs

How to check the version of a XFS filesystem on a system, whether it is V5 or later?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since [version 3.15](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c99d609a), the kernel tells you the version of XFS used in each filesystem as it mounts it; `dmesg | grep XFS` should give you something like

```
[1578018.463269] XFS (loop0): Mounting V5 Filesystem
```

Instead of `loop0` on your system you'll get the underlying device, and `V5` will be replaced by whatever version your filesystem uses.

Older kernels officially supported XFS version 4 filesystems, but could mount version 5 filesystems (since mid 2013); for the latter, the kernel would print

> Version 5 superblock detected. This kernel has EXPERIMENTAL support enabled!

when the filesystem was mounted.

Comment: I get something like this:  1.342982] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, large block/inode numbers, no debug enabled
[    1.345446] XFS (dm-0): Mounting Filesystem
[    1.497979] XFS (dm-0): Starting recovery (logdev: internal)
[    1.587471] XFS (dm-0): Ending recovery (logdev: internal)
[    6.980611] XFS (sda2): Mounting Filesystem
[    9.675872] XFS (sda2): Ending clean mount

Comment: @MikasaAckerman OK, that means you're using a kernel older than 3.15, and a version 4 filesystem (see my updated answer for details).

Comment: This answer does not help, when you are unable to mount the filesystem (which in turn could be the reason why you want to find out the version number at all). Happens when you try to mount an XFS filesystem with an older kernel.

Comment: @U.Windl yes, see [sebasth’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/464939/86440).

Answer (score 13):

You can check the on disk format version of a XFS file system with [`xfs_db`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/xfs_db.8.html).

Example output of an old (V4) XFS file system on my system:

```
xfs_db -r /dev/...
xfs_db> version
versionnum [0xb5b4+0x8a] = V4,NLINK,DIRV2,ATTR,ALIGN,DALIGN,LOGV2,EXTFLG,MOREBITS,ATTR2,LAZYSBCOUNT,PROJID32BIT
```

Output of a new (V5) XFS file system (created with xfsprogs version 4.9.0):

```
xfs_db -r /dev/...
xfs_db> version
versionnum [0xb4a5+0x18a] = V5,NLINK,DIRV2,ALIGN,LOGV2,EXTFLG,MOREBITS,ATTR2,LAZYSBCOUNT,PROJID32BIT,CRC,FTYPE,FINOBT
```

Comment: Great! This also works for non-mounted partitions!

Answer (score -1):

We can check using below command.

```
# yum list installed | grep xfs
```

[image]

```
# yum info xfsprogs
```

[image]

Comment: This only shows the installed version of xfsprogs tools. The question is about the the version of file system on disk format on an existing file system. xfsprogs version doesn't tell which on disk format version is used on existing  file systems: file systems created with older versions of xfsprogs will have an older on disk format version.