# Why does this use of `cp -a` not preserve creation time?

Tags: filesystems, cp, timestamps

I copy some directories with `-a` in order to `preserve=all` which I understood would include creation times:

```
cp -a ./* /mnt/destination/
```

When inspecting the resulting directories in the destination they all have creation time set to the current time, <del>while their contents seem to have preserved their creation times.</del>

**Why aren't the creation dates of the <del>top level</del> directories preserved?**

The source is HFS+ and the destination is btrfs.

---

Excerpts of directory listings of destination and source:

```
$ ls -hal --time=creation
total 16K
drwxrwxr-x 1 andreas andreas   74 sep  2 23:25  .
drwx------ 1 andreas andreas  310 apr 26 17:08  ..
drwx------ 1 andreas andreas 2,3K sep  2 23:45  Library

$ ls -hal --time=creation /mnt/source
total 8,1M
drwxrwxr-x  1 andreas andreas   15 mar 28  2022  .
drwxr-x---+ 3 root    root    4,0K aug  9  2022  ..
drwx------  1 andreas andreas   95 apr 15  2019  Library
```

##### Update

Judging by the answers and comments I concluded that I must have made a mistake when I inspected the dates of subdirectories. I did. My fault — my expectations of the result blinded me of what I was looking at. That part of the question has been dropped.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us how you are checking creation times. Ideally, show us what you are copying, where from, and where to, so we can try and reproduce locally. Are you sure you're not looking at modification time which will be changed since you just moved something into those directories?

Comment: @terdon Thanks. I added `ls` outputs. The first indicator was in the "Created" column in Ubuntu's Files app though. Not sure of the exact details needed to recreate it, but it's from files copied by macOS to a HFS+ formatted USB stick to btrfs on a USB attached HDD, using Ubuntu 23.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4. The example shows my macOS user's Library directory copied "exactly" by macOS Ventura's Finder onto the source volume.

Comment: To preserve times, perhaps use rsync instead:   rsync -a  ./  /mnt/destination/

Comment: @DMcKeon Thanks for the tip. I mostly want to clear up potential gaps in my understanding, since I think it would be convenient to have confidence in `cp` as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Traditional unix filesystems don't have creation time, only ctime.  ctime is *change* time, not creation time.  Change time can't be set via OS calls except to change it to the current time.   Changing permissions or changing atime or mtime will set ctime to the current time.

Having said that, it seems that even though creation time is not part of POSIX, many filesystems seem to have added it, see [What file systems on Linux store the creation time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/what-file-systems-on-linux-store-the-creation-time)

However, even for filesystems that support it, it isn't standardized, so support for creation time in POSIX tools is not guaranteed, and even on filesystems that support it, it may not be set.  If you are seeing it set some times and not others, or not consistently set, possibly multiple tools with varying support are involved, or there is only partial support in those tools.

The linux specific `statx` function call supports atime, btime, ctime, and mtime, where **btime** is marked as creation time.   However, this only reads the times.  (Note that various filesystems reference creation time in various ways including birthtime btime crtime and otime.)

Digging deeper, gnu coreutils cp documents setting time via the `utimensat` function call, which claims POSIX-1.2008 conformance.  This call only supports modifying **atime** and **mtime** but researching this, I could not determine if this is because POSIX only supports atime and mtime (with ctime not settable), or if it is because both ctime and btime are basically immutable, changes only allowed by the operating system, setting them to the current time at the appropriate events.

Comment: Thanks. If we assume creation times do not actually exist on btrfs, or even if there's just no api to set it, then it's still inexplicable how the *contents* of the directories had their same time stamp fields (`time=creation` in `ls`) set to the actual original dates (i.e. years ago) during the copy. If I understood you right, these times should also have been set to the current time. I would have expected `cp` to be consistent with the same field.

Comment: btrfs might be one of the ones that has a creation time.  It is possible that `cp` doesn't know how to set it.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly that you're suggesting that `cp` only has to know how to set that field for the top level directories being transferred? Then how do subdirectories have their fields set?

Comment: It could also be a bug in cp.  But considering that POSIX doesn't support creation time, it's surprising if cp does anything with it.

Comment: POSIX specifies a minimal set of features, there is no operating system which *only* implements POSIX. It’s common for “POSIX” tools such as `cp` to support more features than specified in POSIX. However as far as I‘m aware there’s no way of changing a file’s creation time after its creation.

Comment: My point is that any features that are not POSIX are implemented inconsistently at best and the semantics of creation date are not defined for linux.

Comment: @StephenKitt Well, you're both right insofar as that I'm wrong regarding the contents of the moved directories. Question updated. Still, the fact that `cp` offers to `preserve=timestamps` gives me *quite* the opposite expectations to the reality you two have described, but now I know.

Comment: @user10489: GNU coreutils have never tried to stay restricted to only what POSIX supports, quite the opposite. Reflinks are not POSIX; coreutils `cp` supports them. Linux has a "creation time" field in statx() now – coreutils had support for it for a long time before that.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, I should have looked at statx, I'll update the answer with that.

Answer (score 4):

The only time stamps that can be set to arbitrary values (using the `utime()`, `utimes()`, `utimensat()`, `futimens()` system calls) are the *last modification time* aka mtime and *last access time* aka atime.

The *change status time* aka ctime and *birth/creation time* (btime/crtime) where supported can't be *faked* (set arbitrarily), so `cp -a`, like any other software cannot create a file with a birth time other than that corresponding to the time it was created.

Doing a `ln foo bar` inplace of `cp foo bar` or using the `-l` option of GNU `cp` would result in `bar` having the same timestamps including creation time as `foo`, but note that in that case, `foo` and `bar` are the same file (with two different names).

Comment: creation time is "crtime" on _some_ filesystems.  Other filesystems might use a different name in the data structure.  It isn't standard and it isn't consistently implemented.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I think you're supposed read "birth/creation time" as *one* concept, represented by *multiple* field names "crtime, btime". As a one-to-many relationship the mismatch goes away.

Comment: @Andreas Kamil's point is that since it says "birth/creation", the parenthesis should say "btime/crtime" to match that order (or vice versa), instead of the current "crtime/btime"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that software installers on MacOS preserve the creation time from the original site. This requires "faking" it when installing on the target.